# Making the middle of a pointer NUL; does it work?

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to memory after ‘\0’ in a C string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170808/what-happens-to-memory-after-0-in-a-c-string)

Is it possible to make a pointer's, say, third element NUL ('\0'), thereafter "erasing" the pointers remaining elements?

Comment: Uhh.. "pointers remaining elements" is such a bad construct. What is that phrase *supposed* to mean? Also, `NUL` is used almost exclusively with *characters* and using it in this context is very dubious: `NUL` it is the [ASCII] *character* represented by the integer 0 (aka `'\0'`).

Comment: Can you show us what you have, and what you want the end result to be?

Comment: You're presumably talking about a C-style string rather than pointers in general ?

Comment: A pointer doesn't have elements. If you mean a pointer to the start of an array, then the answer is no. You cannot erase elements by placing a zero in front of them.

Comment: Voting to reopen. As it stands, the question doesn't even mention C strings.

Comment: The OP does confirm that he is asking about strings in one of his comments below - the question is just not very well worded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about C-style strings then yes, kind of:

```
char s[] = "abcdefgh";   // s = "abcdefgh"
                         // (actually contains 9 characters: "abcdefgh\0")

s[3] = '\0';             // s = "abc"
                         // (still contains 9 characters, but now: "abc\0efgh\0")
```

Note that the characters beyond `s[3]` haven't magically disappeared at this point - it's just that displaying the string, or passing it to any function that takes a C-style string, results in the string only appearing to contain three characters. You can still do e.g.

```
s[3] = 'x';              // s = "abcxefgh"
                         // (still contains 9 characters, but now: "abcxefgh\0")
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I hadn't clarified.  This was what I was looking for.  Does anything interesting happen to the "lost" elements?

Comment: No - nothing interesting - the characters are still there - see edit above.

Comment: No, they stay there (but conceptually the string has been cut).

Comment: Importantly, if you replace the character again with a non 0 character, `s[3]='x';`, then you get the string back as "abcxefgh".

Comment: @Michael: good point - have now added this