# QByteArray to char*, sending with libcurl

Tags: c++, qt, libcurl

I'm having trouble with saving a QPixmap to QByteArray, then writing it to char*.
For example i'm trying to write to a file with ofstream.

```
                 QByteArray bytes;
                 QBuffer buff(&bytes);
                 buff.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
                 pixmap.save(&buff, "PNG");

                 QString str(bytes);

                 char *data;
                 data =  (char*)qstrdup(str.toAscii().constData());

                ofstream myfile;
                 myfile.open ("test.jpg");
                   myfile << data;
                   myfile.close();
```

But all i get in that file is:

```
‰PNG
```

The reason i need a char* , is because i'm having some permission problems when writing to disk, then sending with libcurl.
I want to load it to a char* , then send it directly from memory.

Comment: Do you have the JPEG or PNG image format plugins installed with your Qt installation? Also, you should decide between the PNG or JPEG formats.

Comment: yes, i had jpeg plugin problems, but png seems fine, since it works when i try pixmap.save(filename,format) in windows.

Comment: Remind me again, my libcurl is a bit rusty, what is the option used to send in this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encounter a null-byte.  You'll need something like [`write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), because the `<<` operator doesn't allow you to tell how long the string is and stops writing at the first null byte:

```
const QByteArray array = str.toAscii();
myfile.write(array.constData(), array.size());
```

Comment: I think this is very likely the problem but the OP may also want to use buff.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) since they are writing to the buffer and just in case pixmap.save() doesn't close it, follow it with buff.close().

Comment: yes,that works thank you, but im writing to a file, just to see if i can get the QByteArray to char*.
Thing im asking for is, how do i get that array to char*.
i tried strcpy(data,array.constData()); but it doesnt work.

Comment: strcpy also depends on the null-byte, try memcopy(data, array.constData(), array.size()).

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem using this:

```
 memcpy(data,bytes.constData(),bytes.size()+1);
```

Should have tried that at least.

Comment: The +1 isn't strictly necessary, because `bytes.constData()` is exactly `bytes.size()` long.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related, but is there any reason you use libcurl instead of the integrated QNetworkAccessManager?

Comment: never tried it, im kind of used to libcurl.
but i guess i will give it a try once.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `strdup()`. This method is doing this

```
char *strdup (const char *s) {
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   // Space for length plus nul
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;          // No memory
    strcpy (d,s);                        // Copy the characters
    return d;                            // Return the new string
}
```

more info here: [strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

so that you get a `char*`, whereas `ConstData()` will return a `const char*`