# Retaining C memory throughout the function

Tags: c, memory, allocation

Assuming I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
SOMESTRUCTURE *info;
info = malloc(sizeof(SOMESTRUCTURE));

while(something...)
{
     info->mini[0] = malloc(sizeof(SOMESTRUCTURE *)); // It's a structure inside the same structure
     while(something...)
     {
           info->mini[x]->name = malloc(sizeof(char *)*strlen(name));
           printf("%s\n", info->mini[0]->name); // This prints out the correct value
     }
}

printf("%s\n", info->mini[0]->name); // But now the value is lost and is null
```

How can I make the info->mini[0]->name value apply throughout the entire function?

Comment: This is very messy. Give some proper code.

Comment: Don't anyone else's bells ring when they're seeing `malloc(sizeof(char *)*n)`, here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that should still be available to you. The only way you could lose the value would be if `x` were 0 on one of the iterations of your `while` loop or if you execute the `malloc` inside the outer loop without entering the inner loop - it's hard to tell if this is possible since you don't specify what `something` is in both cases.

It's true that variable created within a certain scope will disappear when you exit that scope but that isn't the case here. Allocated memory will survive scope changes. A given *pointer* to that memory may not but your pointer in this case (`info` is still in scope when you exit the outer `while` statement).

I do see one other potential problem - your `malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(name))` should probably be `malloc(strlen(name) + 1)` (since `sizeof(char)` is always 1). It probably works because a `char *` will normally be bigger than a `char` but it's the wrong way to do it nonetheless.

However, I cannot see anywhere in your code where you actually *set* `info->mini[0]->name` to anything so I'm at a loss as to how it can ever have a correct value, unless it's somehow picking up a value from a previous `malloc` (this is possible since `malloc` itself is not required to clear the memory it gives to you).

You should post your actual code or preferably the smallest piece of code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: The name buf is allocated within the loop, so x must be zero at some stage. His code is too messy & incomplete to make any worthwhile assumptions.

Comment: Just using `malloc(strlen(name) + 1)` is the only reasonable idiom I know for a dynamic allocation of a string...

Answer (score 1):

make sure x is never 0

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use glib's `g_strdup` function, see [API](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup) - You'll find in glib many useful functions to handle strings :

So in your case to *duplicate* the string `name` you'd just do ...

```
info->mini[x]->name = g_strdup(name);
```

**Edited**
As commented ... you can use standard [strdup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) to get the same functionality:

```
info->mini[x]->name = strdup(name);
```

**End Edition**

By doing this, `info->mini[x]->name` will point to a dynamic allocated memory space that will be available outside your function - unless you *free* it.

If you don't want to use glib then:

```
info->mini[x]->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(name) + 1));
strcpy(info->mini[x]->name,name);
```

In this case mind that the malloc is of `sizeof(char)` because a string is an array of chars not of `char *`, as you had before. `+1` is to save last char for null terminated char.

Comment: Or, since a huge number of C implementations _have_ `strdup()`, use it instead. Or, if your implementation doesn't, just write one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802) and not bother about trying to incorporate `glib`. There's many good reasons to use glib, a piddling little thing like strdup isn't one of them :-)

Comment: sure @paxdiablo, my point was that there are many useful functions in glib to handle strings. But, I do agree with you, there're many other functionalities in glib that makes it a very useful lib. Answer edited to make the point that using just plain strdup is also a good option. And +1 to your comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you allocate `info->mini[x]->name`, and on the very next line, print it out.

In between, you don't seem to actually put *any* data into `->name`, so I don't see how it can possibly print the correct value out.

Your allocation of `->name` depends on the value of `x` at that time.  But you never show us `x` being declared, or its value being set.

Please show us information about the declaration and assignments of `x` and where data is actually copied into `->name`.