# using memcpy to copy a structure

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Copying one structure to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931123/copying-one-structure-to-another)

```
       struct node
        {
           int n; 
           struct classifier keys[M-1];
           struct node *p[M];
        }*root=NULL;
```

i have created newnode which is of type node

```
        (*newnode)->keys[i]
```

i want to copy data to keys structure from structure clsf_ptr which is also of same type
can i do it like this,i don't want to initialize each member function

```
       memcpy((*newnode)->keys[i], clsf_ptr)
```

Comment: Duplicates (same user): [copying one structure to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932012/copying-one-structure-to-another) and [Copying one structure to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931123/copying-one-structure-to-another)

Comment: why do you waste our time by asking this 3 times, althoug you accepted the answers?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of [4932012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932012/copying-one-structure-to-another), but not [4931123](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931123/copying-one-structure-to-another).  This is about copying an array from one struct to another.  [4931123](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931123/copying-one-structure-to-another) is about copying a whole struct.  4932012 was wrongly closed as a duplicate (but asking the same question again only makes the situation worse.)

Comment: @stacker The FAQ says "be nice". asir did not in fact ask the same question 3 times, they are different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, that should probably be:

```
memcpy(&(newnode->keys[i]), &clsf_ptr, sizeof(struct classifier));
```

(assuming `newnode` is a pointer-to-`node`, and `clsf_ptr` is a classifier`).

Also, struct assignment is legal in C, so you could just do:

```
newnode->keys[i] = clsf_ptr;
```

Note that both of these approaches only do a [*shallow copy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy).  So if `struct classifier` has pointers to memory, the pointers themselves will be copied, rather than creating new copies of the memory.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth @ newnode is a pointer to node but clsf_ptr is not a pointer to classifier

Comment: @asir: What is it, then?  If it's anything else, it's not a very good variable name!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : it is just a instance of classifier, in structure classifier with instance clsf_ptr i have initialized some data, i have to copy that data to (*newnode)->keys[i] location

Comment: @asir: Ok, see the updates to my answer above!

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth : sorry for bugging you again,just stated coding in C a month ago, in other case i have instance of node which is not a pointer and even that of classifier, so is this syntax correct                                                    memcpy((newnode->keys[i]),&clsf_ptr,  sizeof(struct classifier)))

Comment: If `newnode` is a pointer, then you need to use `->keys[i]`, otherwise you need to use `.keys[i]`.  Either way, you need to provide `memcpy` with an *address*, so you must use the `&` operator.  So either `&(newnode->keys[i])` or `&(newnode.keys[i])`.