# assign a string value to pointer

Tags: c

```
char *tempMonth;

char month[4];
month[0]='j';
month[1]='a';
month[2]='n';
month[3]='\0';
```

how to assign month to tempMonth? thanks

and how to print it out finally?

thanks

Answer (score 12):

In C, `month == &month[0]` (in most cases) and these equals a `char *` or character pointer.

So you can do:

```
tempMonth=month;
```

This will point the unassigned pointer `tempMonth` to point to the literal bytes allocated in the other 5 lines of your post.

To make a string literal, it is also simpler to do this:

```
char month[]="jan";
```

Alternatively (though you're not allowed to modify the characters in this one):

```
char *month="jan";
```

The compiler will automatically allocate the length of the literal on the right side of the `month[]` with a proper NULL terminated C string and `month` will point to the literal.

To print it:

```
printf("That string by golly is: %s\n", tempMonth);
```

You may wish to review [C strings and C string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Strings).

Comment: just some suggestions: change `=` to `==` in the first line and make it clear that `month == &month[0]` _mostly._ Not so when using sizeof or certain other language features.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a copy of the *pointer,* you can use:

```
tempmonth = month;
```

but that means both point to the same underlying data - change one and it affects both.

If you want independent strings, there's a good chance your system will have `strdup`, in which case you can use:

```
tempmonth = strdup (month);
// Check that tempmonth != NULL.
```

If your implementation *doesn't* have `strdup`, [get one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802):

```
char *strdup (const char *s) {
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   // Allocate memory
    if (d != NULL) strcpy (d,s);         // Copy string if okay
    return d;                            // Return new memory
}
```

For printing out strings in a formatted fashion, look at the `printf` family although, for a simple string like this going to standard output, `puts` may be good enough (and likely more efficient).

Answer (score 2):

```
tempMonth = month
```

When you assign a value to a pointer - it's a pointer, not a string. By assigning as above, you won't miraculously have two copies of the same string, you'll have two pointers (`month` and `tempMonth`) pointing to the **same** string.

If what you want is a copy - you need to allocate memory (using `malloc`) and then actually copy the values (using `strcpy` if it's a null-terminated string, `memcpy` or a loop otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

```
tempmonth = malloc (strlen (month) + 1); // allocate space
strcpy (tempMonth, month);               //copy array of chars
```

Remember to:

```
include <string.h>
```

Comment: There's a buffer overflow waiting to happen.  Always use `strncpy`, and make sure tempMonth points to properly allocated memory.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I think your allocation should be for `strlen(month)+1`. `sizeof(tempmonth)` is the size of the _pointer._

Comment: Fixed and upvoted. You know, you don't _have_ to leave your answers as they are if you want to change them (I think you can edit your own posts at _any_ rep level).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "string.h" // or #include <cstring> if you're using C++

char *tempMonth;
tempMonth = malloc(strlen(month) + 1);
strcpy(tempMonth, month);
printf("%s", tempMonth);
```

Comment: Some would say that, if you use `printf` or `malloc`, then you couldn't possibly be using C++ - you're stuck in purgatory awaiting full conversion :-)

Comment: true. you can still include C libs though. you never know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug","Sep","Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

and get access

```
printf("%s\n", months[0]);
```