# Arrays in C not working

Tags: c, arrays

Well, I declared a global array of chars like this char * strarr[];

in a method I am tokenising a line and try to put everything into that array like this

```
*line =  strtok(s, " ");

while (line != NULL) {
  *line = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

seems like this is not working.. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context of the code, and more details of what you're seeing as the problem?

Comment: it says tentative array definition assumed to have one element...

Comment: @MattD - Then what is the point of having array of pointers. Just `char*` would be sufficient. You don't even know how many tokens are going to present in a sequence to have an array to hold pointers to these tokens.

Comment: Note that your array is actually of pointers to char, not of chars. The difference is important.

Comment: You have left out many important details. Please provide a complete, minimal example program. For more information about how to produce such a program, and why it is important, please see http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any number of things could be going wrong with the code you haven't shown us, such as undefined behaviour by `strtok`ing a string constatnt, or getting your parameters wrong when calling the function.

But the most likely problem from the code we *can* see is the use of `*line` instead of `line`, assuming that `line` is of type `char *`.

Use the following code as a baseline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "My name is paxdiablo";

    // Start tokenising words.

    char *line =  strtok (str, " ");
    while (line != NULL) {
        // Print current token and get next word.

        printf ("[%s]\n", line);
        line = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
[My]
[name]
[is]
[paxdiablo]
```

and should be easily modifiable into something you can use.

Be aware that, if you're trying to save the character pointers returned from `strtok` (which would make sense for using `*line`), they are transitory and will not be what you expect after you're done. That's because modifications are made in-place within the source string. You can do it with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char *word[4];         // The array of words.
    size_t i;              // General counter.
    size_t nextword = 0;   // For preventing array overflow.

    char str[] = "My name is paxdiablo";

    // Start tokenising.

    char *line =  strtok (str, " ");
    while (line != NULL) {
        // If array not full, duplicate string to array and advance index.

        if (nextword < sizeof(word) / sizeof(*word))
            word[nextword++] = strdup (line);

        // Get next word.

        line = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Print out all stored words.

    for (i = 0; i < nextword; i++)
        printf ("[%s]\n", word[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the *specific* size of the `word` array in that code above. The use of `char * strarr[]` in your code, along with the message `tentative array definition assumed to have one element` is almost certainly where the problem lies.

If your implementation doesn't come with a `strdup`, you can get a reasonably-priced one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802) :-)

Comment: what if char str is outside the main method?

Comment: @MattD, `strok` would modify `str`. I guess you may want to make a copy of it (`strcpy`).

Comment: can I not simple declare an empty array char arr[] and fill it up afterwards??

Comment: @MattD: no, what you have there is an incomplete type. The reason you can get away with that for `argv` is because the startup code has already done the grunt work for you, setting `argc` to the size and even `argv[argc]` to null. There is no such setup for `char xyz[]`, the compiler literally doesn't know how big that should be.