# Strdup() and strcpy

Tags: c++, c

```
void x( )
{
    strcpy(a, strdup(p) );
}
```

(error) Allocation with strdup, strcpy doesn't release it

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with above statement and why I am getting this error?

Comment: what the heck are you trying to do?

Comment: nothing  :D   actually just started programming,while reading forms i saw this function tried some combinations...(just for fun)

Comment: Depending on your needs, you should do either `a = strdup(p);` (`a` is now dynamically allocated) or `strcpy(a, p);` (assumes `a` already points to a buffer of sufficient size). Combining those calls is pointless.

Comment: actually i got this code from somewhere....i didnt know about strdup() function and also they said there are chances of memory leaks...i didnt know that strdup will use malloc and allocate memory i thought it will create an temporary variable ....so it will be removed from memory when scope of that function ends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are leaking memory. The call to `strdup` allocates memory which is not freed. The pointer to the memory that is passed to `strcpy` is never saved anywhere and the compiler can therefore prove that it is leaked.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do since `strdup` performs both allocation and copying, the call to `strcpy` seems superfluous.

Comment: hmm...actually i read from a post that strdup will make an string or copy it  and will return its address,so strcpy should be able to catch that address and copy them.

Comment: You don't understand. `strdup` allocates memory. That is then passed to `strcpy`, but `strcpy` does not deallocate that memory since that is not its job. Thus the memory allocated by `strdup` is never freed.

Comment: oh got it thanx.....cause we havent stored adress of the new allocated array,we will never be able to delete that :D

Comment: @lokesh That's fine. I was just trying to help you along since you are new.

Answer (score 3):

strdup doing something similar to this (Taken from [paxdiablo's answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802) :-

```
char *strdup (const char *s) {
char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   // Allocate memory
if (d != NULL)
    strcpy (d,s);                    // Copy string 
return d;                            // Return new memory
```

}

SO leaking the memory which has been allocated inside strdup leads to that error .

Comment: Mate, if you're going to "lift" my code, either credit me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802) or disguise the fact with a little editing :-) Just joking, but I've only just gone back and edited that answer recently so I recognised it instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `strdup` calls `malloc()` inside and passes the resulting pointer to your code. Your code doesn't take ownership of that allocated memory and it is leaked. You code is roughly doing this:

```
char* duplicate = malloc(strlen(p)+1); //first part of strdup
memcpy(dupliate,p); //second part of strdup
memcpy(a, duplicate);//memcpy in your code
```

the above code doesn't `free()` memory pointed to by `duplicate`.