# Using malloc to allocate memory for a string (c++ source)

Tags: c, windows, malloc

I'm trying to create an array of a struct, which I have done and I have to receive an input from the user. The first piece of data would be the description (a string). I have to allocate memory for it as well. I'm not how big the string is going to be to I want to check as it's going in, but I don't think I've set it up right. Can anyone give me a hint or a page I can look at to figure it out?

Greatly appreciated. Here are the important snipits of code:

```
struct myExpenses
{
    char *description;
    float cost;
};


int main (void)
{


struct myExpenses *pData = NULL;
struct myExpenses expenses[60];
int exit=0;
int i = 0;
char buffer[81] = "";


printf("Please enter all your descriptions:\n");
for (i=0;i < 60; i++)
{
    fgets(buffer,stdin);
    expenses[i].description=(char *)malloc sizeof(buffer);

}
```

Comment: You've tagged this as `C++` but it looks like plain `C` code ?

Comment: Since this is specifically C++, and not C, is there a reason why you're using `char[]`s as opposed to `std::string`s?

Comment: Sorry, it's a C++ course, so I was sorta on autopilot. 
@AusCbloke: I don't understand what you're referring to.

Comment: Dont typecast the return value of `malloc` & AFAIK [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html) take 3 arguments

Comment: That `fgets` call is going to blow up in your face. Where's the maxlen parameter?

Comment: Sorry what?
If you mean if a bad input is to be inserted? Because that's something I'm not to worry about as all input is to be perfect, so for this I don't need checking.

That's if this is what you're referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using malloc() you could use strdup that would automatically allocate the right sized buffer for you.

```
expenses[i].description = strdup( buffer );
```

Comment: wow. Thanks, that works! 
But what would it look like if I chose to use malloc?

Comment: That would be: expenses[i].description = (char*) malloc( strlen( buffer ) + 1 );  strcpy( expenses[i].description, buffer );

Comment: There is no strdup in standard C - you may have to write your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802

Comment: @PaulMitchell: It is preferable not to typecast return value of `malloc` in C & also it does not *assure* you of memory being initalized to `0`, so maybe `calloc`?

Comment: Thanks another.anon.coward.  OP asked how it would be done with malloc.  Incidentally, why would you want the memory initialised to zeros?

Comment: @PaulMitchell: Well you have to assure `NUL` termination thats why I said that! You have correctly allocated `strlen +1` space, but what about `NUL` termination is what I was wondering

Comment: What if the memory wasn't allocated correctly, wouldn't I need checking for NULL?

Comment: @another.anon.coward.  Good idea, belt and braces.  I like your thinking.  I was just planning to depend on the null character that strcpy would put there.  But better to make sure the entire buffer is filled with zeros first I suppose.

Comment: @Robsta, yes you're correct.  After the malloc() you should only contonue to copy the string into the newly allocated memory if the returned pointer is not NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Besides you missing a pair of parentheses around the `malloc` call and not really telling what the problem is, you just allocate the memory but do not copy the string. It can be done in one function call instead with the `strdup` function:

```
printf("Please enter all your descriptions:\n");
for (i=0;i < 60; i++)
{
    fgets(buffer,stdin);
    expenses[i].description=strdup(buffer);
}
```

Remember to call `free` on all the descriptions when you are done with them, or you will have a memory leak.

**Edit** How to use `free` on the given example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    free(expenses[i].description);
```

Comment: How do I go about calling the free?
I know it's the free() function (I believe) but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: @Robsta It's just to call `free` with a pointer allocated by `malloc`, `calloc` or functions that uses those allocation functions, like `strdup`: `free(pointer);`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much as well, I appreciate the help and time.