# How to assign a struct member with a value returned by other function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct

I'm trying to make a multithreaded program.
I can compile it successfully, but my program always crashes.

Here is my code snippet :

```
// in global declaration
typedef struct MyData {
    int nSumber;
    char *szFileName;
} MYDATA, *PMYDATA;

PMYDATA pData[MAX_THREAD];

// in my OpenDialog function
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szFile[MAX_PATH];
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
    // I think this line that makes my program crash
    pData[0]->szFileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `pData` array contains pointers to `MYDATA` that are not pointing to valid memory because you haven't allocated any memory yet.

```
if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) {
  pData[0] = new MYDATA();
  pData[0]->szFileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
}
```

And now you need to call `delete` on *each* allocated `pData` element to release the memory.

So, instead of going through all that trouble, use an `std::vector<MYDATA>`.

```
std::vector<MYDATA> dataVec;

// ...

if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) {
  MYDATA data;
  data.szFileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
  data.nSumber = something; // you probably want to init this also
  dataVec.push_back(data);
}
```

I'm not sure about `szFileName` being a `char *` and simply pointing it to `ofn.lpstrFile`. You may need to allocate memory and store the file name in the `struct`. If that's the case, change `szFileName` to `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Comment: I have try std::string instead of char * but the problem still goes on. Is there any other simple way (i'm beginner) for retrieving a file name and assign it to struct ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1888256 It's hard to say what problems you're having given the code you've posted. If you compile and run in debug mode, your debugger should automatically break when an exception is encountered and tell you what line the error happened at.

Comment: i use devcpp and this is what igot from debugger, "Thread 1 stopped in OpenDialog(HWND__*, int) at line 5808667 in  with Segmentation fault". But i have fixed the crash problem by following this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847370/using-malloc-to-allocate-memory-for-a-string-c-source). But know, i face new problem, i can't convert my struct to LPVOID to CreateThread() function. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves out a lot of detail, but if `char szFile[MAX_PATH]` is local to a function it is on the stack.  You can't save it in a global variable and expect it to be used elsewhere because the stack space will be re-used as soon as `szFile` goes out of scope (at the next `}` or the end of the function).

For a quick test try `ofn.lpstrFile = new char[MAX_PATH]` and see if your crash goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Ben. szFile is local. I have try your advise, but my program still crash. Any idea?

Comment: @user1888256: You may have multiple bugs:  See the answers that talk about how to allocate `pData`

Answer (score 0):

This only allocates an array of pointers to the data:

```
PMYDATA pData[MAX_THREAD];
```

You need to actually allocate a `MYDATA` at `pData[0]` for this to be valid.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply gil. I have try your advise but it still keeps crasing. I just follow from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).