# QByteArray convert to/from unsigned char *

Tags: qt, type-conversion

```
QByteArray inArray = " ... ";
unsigned char *in = convert1(inArray);
unsigned char *out;
someFunction(in, out);
QByteArray outArray = convert2(out);
```

the question is how can I correctly make these conversions (convert1 and convert2). 
I cannot change someFunction(unsigned char *, unsigned char *), but I have to work with QByteArray here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qt has really great [docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html), you should use them.

If someFunction doesn't modify or store pointer to in data you can use this:

```
QByteArray inArray = " ... ";
unsigned char *out;
someFunction((unsigned char*)(inArray.data()), out);
QByteArray outArray((char*)out);
```

Otherwise you have to make a deep copy of the char* returned by QByteArray::data() (see the docs for code snippet).

Comment: `QByteArray outArray = QByteArray::fromRawData(out, strlen(out));` If you are not going to use `out`.

Comment: If I use fromRawData, I get "invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char*'". so I tried QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(out), part.length()).

Comment: The solution by chalup seems to be good and I tried it before, but I got errors with it. Apparently the case is in something else.

Answer (score 0):

if `someFunction` takes a `const char*` args then just use `ConstData()` or `data()` in `QByteArray` class.

if you need a `char*`, you can then use strdup(). This method is doing this

```
char *strdup (const char *s) {
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   // Space for length plus nul
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;          // No memory
    strcpy (d,s);                        // Copy the characters
    return d;                            // Return the new string
}
```

more info here:  [strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Comment: it's not about const. it's about unsigned.

Comment: I-N-D-E-E-D what about the unsigned char?