# How do I remove the following 'implicit declaration of function' warnings?

Tags: c, lex

How do I compile the lex file with gcc without receiving the following warnings?

```
lex.yy.c: In function `yy_init_buffer':
lex.yy.c:1688: warning: implicit declaration of function `fileno'
lex.l: In function `storeLexeme':
lex.l:134: warning: implicit declaration of function `strdup'
```

These are the libraries I included.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
%}
```

The function yy_init_buffer is not in the file. The following is the function storeLexeme.

```
 int storeLexeme() {
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    char *curr = *(symbolTable + i); 
    if (strcmp(curr, yytext) == 0) {
        return i;
    }
}
char *lexeme = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));
lexeme = (char *)strdup(yytext);
symbolTable[count] = lexeme;
count++;
return (count - 1);
 }
```

How do I remove the warnings?

Comment: I changed the flex tag, as it's about Adobe flex and not the GNU lex clone.

Comment: What platform, UNIX or Windows?

Comment: Those are not 'libraries'; they are 'headers'.  Libraries are used in the link line; the source code references headers.

Answer (score 11):

Neither `strdup` nor `fileno` are ISO C functions, they're part of POSIX.

Now whether they're available on your platform depends on your platform.

---

If you are using the Microsoft tools, you may want to look into [`_fileno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx) for the latter ([`fileno` was deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235401.aspx) in VC2005). A rather excellent version of `strdup` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802).

Although, having blown my own horn with that code, you could also use [`_strdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx) since it replaces the [also-deprecated `strdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235454.aspx) :-)

These should hopefully work okay as-is since they're in `stdio.h` and `string.h`, two of the include files you're already using.

---

If you're on a UNIX derivative, those functions should be available in `stdio.h` (for `fileno`) and `string.h` (for `strdup`). Given that it looks like you're already including those files, the problem is likely elsewhere.

One possibility is if you're compiling in one of the strict modes like `__STRICT_ANSI__` in gcc), where neither would be defined.

You should have a look at the top of your generated `lex.yy.c` and `lex.l` files to confirm that the header files *are* being included and also check the command line parameters you're passing to the compiler.

Comment: Like `_fileno`, there is also `_strdup` if using MS tools.

Comment: Would just like to add here that I am using Linux (debian/ubuntu) and had to compile with -D _GNU_SOURCE to get the compiler to recognize this function from wchar.h

Answer (score 9):

I suggest this option (tell the compiler you are using POSIX):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
```

People seem to have tightened up the feature controls in recent years and hopefully when the consistency is good and widespread we can throw away the automake garbage.

Comment: you may consider to add it once `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=1` in the Makefile (or Makefile.am)

Answer (score 7):

I also had this problem while using flex.

I used `-std=gnu99`rather than `-std=c99` which solved the problem.

```
flex lang.l && gcc -o lexer -std=gnu99 lex.yy.c -lfl
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider adding the following line:

```
extern char *strdup(const char *s);
```

I faced the problem when I compiled with `-std=c99 -pedantic -pedantic-errors`. Adding the above line solved the problem for me.

Comment: `extern` is redundant here. It's a function declaration anyway and without `static` keyword, its linkage is external.

Comment: yeah, as simple as this

Answer (score -1):

You declare the function before you use it:

```
//declare the function
int storeLexeme();

//use the function here
```

or include the header where the function is declared.

C implicitly assumes undeclared functions have return type `int` and deduces the parameters from how you call the function. This is deprecated in C++.

Comment: I did declare the function before I used it after I #included the libraries, and I still receive the warnings.

Comment: It's not the storeLexeme function it's complaining about it's the strdup _called_ from there.

Comment: Did you also declare `strdup` and `fileno` or include the headers?

Comment: @paxdiablo yes, I saw that now, but the principle is still the same.

Answer (score -2):

just place your function below the library calls it will be alright;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30034100)