# Using strdup in C11

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I am able to compile the following using gcc version 4.7.2

```
   #include <string.h>

   int main(){
    char text[] = "String duplicate";
    char* dup = strdup(text);
    return 0;

   }
```

But when I used the --std=c11 flag, I get the following warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

What changed to cause this warning?

Comment: Related : [How do I remove the following 'implicit declaration of function' warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9427145/1870232)

Comment: [This mail](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-factory/2012-06/msg00102.html) suggests `strdup` is standard in C11, but I can't find it anywhere else.

Comment: I don´t think strdup is a C standard, as far I remember is only a POISX function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the manual of **strdup** by

```
man strdup
```

You can find that

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> strdup():
>              _SVID_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
>              || /* Since glibc 2.12: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L

It denotes that **strdup** conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.

So you can get rid of the warnings by

```
gcc -D_BSD_SOURCE -std=c11 <your source file>
```

I guess the warnings are caused by c11 not enabling one of the above macros.

Comment: _BSD_SOURCE is an unusual choice. Using -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L is a more broad and useful standard.

Answer (score 6):

you want --std=gnu11 or --std=c11 -D_GNU_SOURCE