# Why am I getting "error: implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’" when I try to compile on Linux but not on a Mac

Tags: c, linux, macos

As the title states, I am getting the following error: "implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’" when I try to compile on Linux but not on a Mac. I know I can fix it with the simple line `int fileno(FILE *stream);`, but I want to know why this happening.

Comment: Use strict warnings in both environments. I'd be surprised if you get the warning on missing prototype on only one of them then.

Comment: And where is the code which shows this problem?

Comment: Related: [How do I remove the following 'implicit declaration of function' warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9427286/4520911)

Comment: What compilation options are you using?  `-std=c11` or `-std=c99`?  Try `-std=gnu11` or `-std=gnu99` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what ISO C and POSIX have to do with Linux and Mac or what they are. The line of code is this int f = fileno(outputFile);. I'm not looking for a fix, I already have one. What I'm trying to understand is why this is error is happening

Comment: Officially, you have to request POSIX functions by having `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` in effect before the first (POSIX) standard header is included.  If you specify `-std=c11`, then those functions are not declared by defaul.

Comment: [As n.m. suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623177/4520911), try adding a `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1` above `#include <stdio.h>` to explicitly state you are using POSIX.

Comment: "I don't know what ISO C and POSIX have to do with Linux and Mac or what they are" You probably want to learn these things if you plan to produce meaningful C code for these systems.

Answer (score 9):

You should not declare functions provided by a system library. You should *properly* include an appropriate header.

Since `fileno` is not a standard C function, it is not normally declared by in `<stdio.h>` .  You have to define a suitable macro in order to enable the declaration.

```
man fileno
```

> Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> fileno(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE

Defining any of the the three macros before inclusion of  should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you remembered to include `<stdio.h>`, this warning indicates that your `<stdio.h>` does not declare this function.

`fileno` is not a standard function. It is perfectly expected that some implementations do not provide it, especially if you are compiling in strict standard-compliant mode.

If your code still links successfully, this almost certainly means that your Linux compiler settings direct your compiler to work in "strict" mode and thus force `<stdio.h>` to "hide" declaration of `fileno`.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple program in my `Ubuntu 16.04` machine. And it compiles well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf ("%d\n", fileno(stdout));

    return 0;
}
```

I hope you know that `fileno` is present in `<stdio.h>`.
If you have not included the header file, please do so and re-compile.

I am not so sure why Mac version works.

EDIT:

I have not used C99 standard.
I compiled using: `gcc -Wall -Werror test.c`

Comment: Yes I have included <stdio.h>

Comment: You are using wrong compiler flags (e.g. none at all).

Comment: If you don't use the -std=c99 flag, then there's no error because pre-99 C allowed functions without prototypes first and also had int as the default return value so it all works out.