# problems with convert const char* to char* in c

Tags: c, char, constants

```
int A(const char* name){     
    name = "Here you GO!";    
    char* new_name;      
    //strcpy(new_name,name);      
    new_name = const_cast<char *>(name);      
    printf("%s\n", new_name);      
    return 0;    
}
```

This is the source code which I am testing.

one problem is when I use `const_cast<char *>`, it says it is undeclared. (I know it can work under 'g++' compiling)
Anther problem is when I try to use `strcpy` to combine them together, it pops up segmentation fault. 
the premise is I have to use `gcc whatevername.c -std=c99` to compile.

Is anyone offer some suggestion how to solve that. Much appreciate..

Comment: If you see that `const_cast<char *>`works under `g++, but not under `gcc`'s C compiler part, you have something like evidence that it is C++ and not C...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the new string. You were on the right track using `strcpy`, because `const_cast` is C++ only. Edit: Even better use `strdup`as Miroslav suggests.

```
int A(const char* name)
{ 
    name = "Here you GO!";
    char* new_name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    if (new_name) {
        strcpy(new_name,name);
        printf("%s\n", new_name);
    }
    return 0;
]
```

Answer (score 9):

You are getting segmentation fault, because new_name points nowhere.

Solution: allocate memory for new_name. You can either call malloc() and then use strcpy(), or call strdup() which will do both things for you:

```
int A(const char* name){ 
    name = "Here you GO!";

    char* new_name = strdup(name);

    printf("%s\n", new_name);
    return 0;
}
```

See this answer for more details on strdup(): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252802/69868)

Answer (score 4):

`const_cast` is a C++ thing; it doesn't exist in C.

If you want to use `strcpy`, you can't just use an uninitialised pointer (i.e. `new_name`).  You need to allocate sufficient space first (with `malloc`), and then `free` that space when you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated space for new_name. Allocate enough to hold the string you are copying into it.