# when i use strtok(), is there a way to pick out individual tokens?

Tags: c, strtok

if for instance i have a string: `Hi:my:name:is:lacrosse1991:` how could I use `strtok` to retrieve just the `is` (in other words the fourth field)? This would be similar to how you would use cut in bash, where i would just do `cut -d ":" -f 4`. If this is the wrong function to be doing such a thing, please let me know, any help is much appreciated, thanks! (I've just recently started teaching myself C, I apologize ahead of time if these are obvious questions that i am asking)

here is an example of the cut command that I would use

```
x=$(echo "$death" | cut -d ':' -f 4)
y=$(echo "$death" | cut -d ':' -f 5)
z=$(echo "$death" | cut -d ':' -f 6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid `strtok` for this purpose (and most others, for that matter). Under the circumstances, I think I'd just use `sscanf` with a `scanset` conversion:

```
char field_four[128];   
sscanf(input_string, "%*[^:]:%*[^:]:%*[^:]:%127[^:]:", field_four);
```

In this, we start by repeating `%*[^:]:` three times. Each of these reads a string including any characters except a colon, then a colon. The `*` means that should be read from the input, but ignored (not assigned to anything). Then, for the fourth field we have the same thing, except we do *not* include the `*`, so that field *does* get assigned, in this case to `field_four` (though you should obviously use a more meaningful name).

For the fourth field, I've also added a specification of the maximum length. Since `sscanf` always includes a `\0` to terminate the string, but doesn't include it in the count, we need to specify a size one smaller than the size of the buffer.

Comment: turned out to be just what i needed, and simple too! thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

If you know it's the 4th field you just call strtok() 4 times - there is no way of jumping to the 4th field without scanning the entire string ( which is what strtok is doing)

Answer (score 1):

One way to extract the `N`th field (whilst keeping the string in original condition after the call) is to use the following `getFld` function. First, the requisite headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
```

Now the function itself, which I hope is documented well enough:

```
char *getFld (char *srchStr, char delim, int numFld) {
    char *copyStr, *retStr, *tmpStrPtr, delims[2];

    // Make a copy so as to not damage original.

    if ((copyStr = strdup (srchStr)) == NULL) return NULL;

    // Create delimiter string from character.

    delims[0] = delim; delims[1] = '\0';
    retStr = NULL;

    // Start loop, extracting fields.

    tmpStrPtr = strtok (copyStr, delims);
    while (tmpStrPtr != NULL) {
        // If this is the field we want, make a copy.

        if (numFld == 0) retStr = strdup (tmpStrPtr);

        // Get next field.

        tmpStrPtr = strtok (NULL, delims);
        numFld--;
    }

    // Clean up, return field copy (must be freed eventually) or NULL.

    free (copyStr);
    return retStr;
}
```

And, finally, a test program for it:

```
int main (void) {
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "Hi:my:name:is:lacrosse1991";
    char *fld;
    while ((fld = getFld (str, ':', i)) != NULL) {
        printf ("Field %d is '%s'\n", i, fld);
        free (fld);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling and running this, I get:

```
Field 0 is 'Hi'
Field 1 is 'my'
Field 2 is 'name'
Field 3 is 'is'
Field 4 is 'lacrosse1991'
```

Now, keep in mind that `strdup` is not standard C but, if your implementation doesn't have it, you can use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802). You may also want to change the behaviour on `strdup` failure since the current case cannot be distinguished from an out of range field.

But, this code should be fine as a baseline to start with.