# Value of head of linked list silently changes when list grows past 100 elements

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I need to make some operations on a list of files with particular extension (*.bob), all stored in the same directory. The files are image frames, and their name format is frame_XXXX.bob. I don't know the number of frames a priori, and I need to make sure I process them in order (from frame 0 to last one). I read the content of the folder with `struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp)`, but since it doesn't guarantee files will be read in alphabetical order (even though it always seems to), I want to put them into a single linked list, and then sort them before processing further.
I save the head of the list before populating it to a pointer `filesListStart`, then read the entire folder content, adding each entry to the list if it has ".bob" extension. This all works great when I have up to 100 frames, but for some reason breaks down above that - the value of what pointer `filesListStart` points at doesn't contain the filename of the first entry in the list anymore. The code doesn't use any numerals, so I don't know what would be the significance of going over 100 elements.
I wrote out memory address of `filesListStart` before I start populating the list, and after, and they are the same, but values they show at magically change. When I set `filesListStart` it points at object with field `fileName` equals to "frame_0000.bob" (which is as expected), but after populating the list the name it points at becomes "e_0102.bob".

The list structure is defined as

```
// List structure
struct FilesList {
  char *fileName ;
  struct FilesList *next ;
} ;
```

The code in question is:

```
DIR *moviesDir ;
moviesDir = opendir("movies") ;

if(moviesDir == NULL)
{
  printf("Make Movie failed to open directory containing bob frames\n") ;
  return ;
}

struct dirent *dirContent ;

// Get first .bob frame name from the directory
dirContent = readdir(moviesDir) ;
// isBobFile(dirContent) returns 1 if entry has ".bob" extension and 0 otherwise
while( !isBobFile(dirContent) )
{
  dirContent = readdir(moviesDir) ;
}

struct FilesList *filesList = (struct FilesList*)
    malloc( sizeof(struct FilesList) ) ;

// Initialize the list start at that first found .bob frame
filesList->fileName = dirContent->d_name;
// And save the head of the list
struct FilesList *filesListStart = filesList ;
printf("FilesListStart: %s\n", filesListStart->fileName) ;
printf("Address is: %p\n", filesListStart) ;

// For all other bob frames
while( (dirContent = readdir(moviesDir) ) != NULL )
{
  if( isBobFile(dirContent) )
  {
    struct FilesList *temporaryNode = (struct FilesList*)
        malloc( sizeof(struct FilesList) );
    temporaryNode->fileName = dirContent->d_name ;
    filesList->next = temporaryNode ;
    filesList = temporaryNode ;
  }
}
// Set the 'next' pointer of the last element in list to NULL
filesList->next = NULL ;
// close stream to directory with .bob frames
closedir(moviesDir) ;

// Check what FilesListStart points at
printf("FilesListStart: %s\n", filesListStart->fileName) ;
printf("Address is: %p\n", filesListStart) ;

// Rest of the code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be making a *copy* of `dirContent->d_name` rather than using the actual value.

The runtime libraries are free to change the contents of that `dirent` structure whenever you call `readdir` and, if all you've stored is it's address, the underlying memory may change. From the POSIX man-pages:

> The pointer returned by readdir() points to data which may be overwritten by another call to readdir() on the same directory stream.

In other words, replace the lines:

```
filesList->fileName = dirContent->d_name;
temporaryNode->fileName = dirContent->d_name ;
```

with:

```
filesList->fileName = strdup (dirContent->d_name);
temporaryNode->fileName = strdup (dirContent->d_name);
```

assuming you have a `strdup`-like function and, if not, you can get one cheap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802).

If it's only changing after 100 calls, it's probably the runtime trying to be a bit more intelligent but even it can't store an infinite number so it probably sets a reasonable limit.

Just remember to free all those char pointers before you free the linked list nodes (somewhere in that "rest of code" section presumably).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I suspected the problem was with `filesList->fileName = dirContent->d_name` as you pointed out, but couldn't figure out how to copy a value from one pointer to another. Any `*(filesList->fileName) = *(dirContent->d_name)` and other contraptions I came up with caused either warnings, segmentation faults, or illegal instructions. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Puchatek: make sure you change the other line as well (which I originally missed) - I've updated the answer to show it.