# strcpy vs strdup

Tags: c, strcpy, strdup

I read that `strcpy` is for copying a string, and `strdup` returns a pointer to a new string to duplicate the string.

Could you please explain what cases do you prefer to use `strcpy` and what cases do you prefer to use `strdup`?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`strcpy(ptr2, ptr1)` is equivalent to `while(*ptr2++ = *ptr1++)`

where as strdup is equivalent to

```
ptr2 = malloc(strlen(ptr1)+1);
strcpy(ptr2,ptr1);
```

([memcpy version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033333/2436175) might be more efficient)

So if you want the string which you have copied to be used in another function (as it is created in heap section) you can use strdup, else strcpy is enough.

Comment: Good answer apart from the last sentence, which is confusing. I guess you mean the lifetime of the `strdup()`ed string can extend beyond the end of the current function, but that could be the case anyway (if the target of `strcpy()` is a caller-provided buffer, a global variable, or itself manually allocated using `malloc()` or `new`).

Comment: Yes it is true that if the caller-provided buffer is a global variable or a dynamic pointer by itself then no need to use strdup

I have just pointed one of the use case scenarios and thanks for completing it.

Comment: Really love the `while(*ptr2++ = *ptr1++)`! :)

Comment: In the while loop, how does the exit condition work?

Comment: @sbhatla In C strings are ended by a nulbyte, which evaluates to false, and an assignment expression evaluates to the assigned value.

Comment: @Aloys If you do use an explict `while(*ptr2++ = *ptr1++)` in your program, don't forget to restore the pointers to their original values.  After the `while` they'll be positioned at the null terminator.

Answer (score 68):

The functions `strcpy` and `strncpy` are part of the C standard library and operate on existing memory. That is, *you* must provide the memory into which the functions copy the string data, and as a corollary, *you* must have your own means of finding out how much memory you need.

By constrast, `strdup` is a Posix function, and it performs dynamic memory allocation for you. It returns a pointer to newly allocated memory into which it has copied the string. But *you* are now responsible for this memory and must eventually `free` it.

That makes `strdup` one of the "hidden `malloc`" convenience functions, and that's presumably also why it is not part of the standard library. As long as you use the standard library, you know that you must call one `free` for every `malloc`/`calloc`. But functions such as `strdup` introduce a hidden `malloc`, and you must treat it the same as a `malloc` for the purpose of memory management. (Another such hidden allocation functions is GCC's `abi::__cxa_demangle()`.) Beware!

Comment: Ahh, I always wondered why this wasn't in stdlib, and now I know.

Answer (score 18):

`strdup` allocates memory for the new string on the heap, while using `strcpy` (or its safer `strncpy` varient) I can copy a string to a pre allocated memory on **either** the heap or the stack.

Comment: Why the emphatic "either"? Is it not possible to use `strcpy` to copy into a static buffer?

Comment: I attempted to stress the difference in usage between the two functions without cluttering the answer with too many memory managment issues. but yes you are correct about static buffers.

Comment: If you don't want clutter, you can just end the answer after "pre allocated memory" :-)

Comment: small nitpick: strncpy isn't safer than strcpy, as it does not guarantee that dest will be null terminated. Even worse, any unused space in the dest buffer will be filled with null terminators. This function was never intended for general usage. If you must use one of these functions, it's best to use strcpy and manually terminate dest.

Answer (score 15):

In the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021039/2436175), the implementation of `strdup` is presented as:

```
ptr2 = malloc(strlen(ptr1)+1);
strcpy(ptr2,ptr1);
```

However, that is somewhat sub-optimal because both `strlen` and `strcpy` need to find the length of the string by checking if each character is a `\0`.

Using `memcpy` should be more efficient:

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {
    size_t len = strlen(src) + 1;
    char *s = malloc(len);
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return (char *)memcpy(s, src, len);
}
```

Comment: Good answer that separates the conceptual use of `strcpy` to implement `strdup` from the practicality of doing so in an efficient way.

Comment: Given that memcpy is dependent upon knowing string length, strlen is going to be called in either case.  memcpy itself is equivalent to `while ( len-- ) { *ptr2++ = *ptr1++ }`, which each time does a subtraction, assignment, and test for zero, and then still has to run an assignment and then two post increments and their assignments anyways.  So this memcpy technique seems less efficient.  These seem like rather trivial distinctions and imaginary optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

`char *strdup(char *pszSrch)`;

`strdup` will allocate storage the size of the original string. If storage allocation is successful, the original string is copied to the duplicate string.

`strdup`d return `NULL` on failure. If memory is not allocated, copy fails `strdup` return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

for *memcpy another implementation is possible without incremental of dest and src :

`while ( n-- ) { dest[n] = src[n] }`