# Having problems with pointers in c

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, valgrind

I have  structure

```
typedef struct song_
{
     char  *artist ;
     char  *title ;
     mtime *lastPlayed ;
} song ;
```

and a function that takes a pointer to a song struct and returns a pointer to a copy of that song

```
song *songCopy(const song *s){
  song *d = NULL ;
  mtime *tmp = NULL ;

  d = malloc(sizeof(song)) ;

  d->artist = malloc(sizeof(*s->artist) + 1) ;
  strcpy(d->artist, s->artist) ; //****

  d->title = malloc(sizeof(*s->title) + 1) ;
  strcpy(d->title, s->title) ;  //****

  if (NULL != s->lastPlayed)
    {
      // copy the last played
      tmp = mtimeCopy(s->lastPlayed) ;
      d->lastPlayed = tmp ;
    }
  else
    {
      // set lastPlayed to NULL
      d->lastPlayed = NULL ;
    }

  return d ;
  }
```

I'm debugging this with valgrind and I'm getting this error message on the starred lines above

```
Invalid write of size 1
==14096==    at 0x402C6C3: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14096==    by 0x8048EC9: songCopy (song.c:104)
==14096==    by 0x80487C6: main (songtest.c:82)
==14096==  Address 0x41fe7a2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==14096==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14096==    by 0x8048EAA: songCopy (song.c:103)
==14096==    by 0x80487C6: main (songtest.c:82)
```

I feel like I have change something with how d is declared but I don't know what

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to use `strlen` not `sizeof` here `sizeof(*s->artist)` and here `sizeof(*s->title) + 1`.

Comment: If you does not like this question, **delete the question itself**, please do not delete the contents of your question, this will make other readers of this question very confused.

Comment: Also, deleting a perfectly good question like this (which was successfully answered) would be completely inconsiderate to Stack Overflow as a whole. I hope your edit was somehow a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easist way would be to use `strdup` to duplicate the strings.

```
  d->artist = strdup(s->artist);
  d->title = strdup(s->title);
```

---

To fix your actual problem, you need to use `strlen` and not `sizeof`.

```
  d->artist = malloc(strlen(s->artist) + 1) ;
  strcpy(d->artist, s->artist);

  d->title = malloc(strlen(s->title) + 1) ;
  strcpy(d->title, s->title);
```

The problem is that this:

```
  sizeof(*s->artist)
```

Is returning `sizeof(char)`, which is most likely 1.

Comment: for more on that topic, please see that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14021039/1290438)