# I don't understand why I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, argv, strcpy

I am writing a C program which searches for a string inside a file. When I compile and execute the program from the command line, I get the segmentation fault error. I know that this error means that I do not have access to the memory I am trying to write to, but I do not see how this is occurring in my program. Here is the segment of code in my `main` function where the error is occurring:

```
int num_of_arguments = argc;
char *filename = argv[2];
char *search_string;

strcpy(search_string, argv[1]);

int i = 0;
while (search_string[i]) {
    tolower(search_string[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Your `search_string` is a uninitialized pointer pointing to nowhere. And you are trying to `strcpy` that `argv[1]` to nowhere. Hence the crash.

Comment: use ``search_string=strdup(argv[1]) ``instead of strcpy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
 strcpy(search_string, argv[1]);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you're trying to to write into unitialized memory, pointed by `search_string`. As you've not initialized `search_string` explicitly, the pointer (pointer value) is indeterminate and most likely it points to some memory location that is not accessible from your program. Thus the pointer essentially points to *invalid* memory location.

You need to allocate memory to `search_string` before you can *copy* into it.

Otherwise, make `search_string` an array of sufficient length that can hold the contents of `argv[1]` (including null-terminator) before performing `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense now that I think about it. As pointed out in other answers, `strdup()` is a better solution to my problem.

Comment: @CornOnTheKob well, I'm not against using `strdup()`, but just a note, it is not standard C.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `search_string` without initialization, instead of:

```
strcpy(search_string, argv[1]);
```

You should use:

```
search_string=strdup(argv[1]);
```

Look:
[strcpy vs strdup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020380/strcpy-vs-strdup)

Comment: I didn't even know `strdup` exists. I am using this isntead and all is working fine, thank you.