# c: freeing an mallocated object error

Tags: c

Okay, so I have a method which I call. The called method returns a `char*`, which is allocated inside the called method. After having assigned the returned `char*` to a new `char*`, I want to free this, after using it. But Xcode complains and throws an error. It says that the object I try to free is not allocated, which I do not get, since I am sure I allocate it.

Here is my code:

```
void print_r()
{

    char *stateA = isActive(ruter_array[id]->flagg);

    //print out the results etc

    free(stateA);     <-----The program crashes here.


}

char * isActive(unsigned char a_flag)
{
    char *ret = malloc(5);

    if((a_flag & 1) == 1)
    {
        //is active
        ret = "yes";
        return ret;
    }
    ret = "no";
    return ret;

}
```

Its not important to understand what this does, but why is this freeing crashing?

Comment: `isActive` returns a pointer to either the string constant "yes" or the string constant "no", which are not mallocated objects because they're something else (string constants). It also mallocates an object and doesn't return a pointer to that object. (Also, "mallocate" is not a common term, but it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ret = "no";
```

That overwrites the pointer. Change to:

```
strcpy(ret, "no");
```

Same applies for the `"yes"` case.

Also, as pointed out by @DavidSchwartz, for your purposes it is probably not necessary to use dynamically allocated memory. Could just return the string literals directly:

```
char * isActive(unsigned char a_flag)
{
    if((a_flag & 1) == 1)
    {
        //is active
        return "yes";
    }
    return "no";  
}
```

And of course in that case the caller should not `free` the returned value.

Comment: Or don't use `malloc` or `free` at all, since you don't need to.

Comment: Wow. I thought I knew everything I needed when it comes to pointers and memory in c. Apparently, that is not the case. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate some memory and assign the first address of that memory to the pointer `ret`, but `"no"` and `"yes"` are string literals that are stored statically in memory at compile-time. When you do `ret = "no"`, you change the pointer so that it now points to the first character of the string literal `"no"`. So, now you have lost access to the memory that you allocated, and you have a memory leak. But the crash is because you are trying to free memory that was not allocated by `malloc()` or one of its friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `strdup`:

```
char * isActive(unsigned char a_flag)
{
    return strdup((a_flag & 1) == 1 ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021039/6843321) the pointer is still allocated through `malloc` so it can also be freed.