# How to properly implement strcpy in c?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcpy

According to this:
[strcpy vs strdup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020380/strcpy-vs-strdup),
strcpy could be implemented with a loop, they used this `while(*ptr2++ = *ptr1++)`. I have tried to do similar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *des = malloc(10);
    for(char *src="abcdef\0";(*des++ = *src++););
    printf("%s\n",des);
}
```

But that prints nothing, and no error. What went wrong?

Thanks a lot for answers, I have played a bit, and decided how best to design the loop to see how the copying is proceeding byte by byte. This seems the best:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *des = malloc(7);
    for(char *src="abcdef", *p=des; (*p++=*src++); printf("%s\n",des));
}
```

Comment: Learn something from this:  needlessly cramming all those operations into a single line of code made it impossible for you to understand what was actually happening.  There's NOTHING gained from seeing how much code you can cram into a single line.

Comment: @AndrewHenle so you once see a usage of `for loop` in an uncommon way and called it cramming? Well `for loop` is pretty basic concept among all programming, and c has the advantage to use it whatever way you like. I use it a lot in different way that `for(int i =0;i<10;i++)` like you are used to, but that is just my preference.

Comment: @milanHrabos as a very beginner you have a bit too strong opinions. Your code is hard to read and **experienced** programmers prefer to write more lines instead of "compressing" in into this kind of monsters.

Comment: @milanHrabos You had to ask this very question because that one line of code was too complex for you to figure out.  End of story.  "Brevity of code" is cargo-cult BS that causes the very issues that prevented you from being able to understand what your code was doing. There is a whole body of peer-reviewed research that ***demonstrates*** that a human mind can only keep track of a handful of separate states simultaneously - that number usually varies from 3 to 6 or 7 things. The `(*des++ = *src++)` part of your `for` loop **has 6 things going on at once**.  Yeah - you crammed too much there.

Comment: You can learn from this, or you can keep banging your head against brick walls trying to make sense of code that has too much crammed into one line.  Your choice.

Comment: @AndrewHenle and how many of your "separate states" are going on here: `for(char *src="abcdef", *p=des; (*p++=*src++); printf("%s\n",des));`
. Oh, you do not like it? I am sorry for that. For me it looks elegant to pack all information to a loop header and since I am use to see for loop header to contain the most information needed for the body, this one does have all needed. You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502669/for-loop-make-increment-and-accessing-in-one-loop?noredirect=1#comment110535497_62502669, where I am trying to assign value in headerAndNothingWillStopMe

Comment: @milanHrabos Seriously?!?!  "Here's some more 'elegant' code that I wrote that I'm unable to understand. Please help me."  You have two questions where you have such a problem figuring out what your code is doing that you have to ask questions here?  And you continue to defend writing code that way?  I don't care if you want to write code you can't understand even after I've explained to you why you can't understand it - but others at least can learn something. Code that doesn't do what you coded it to do is a mistake, and you are proud that you literally refuse to learn from your mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(char *src="abcdef\0";(*des++ = *src++););
```

the destination pointer `des` is being changed. So after the loop it does not point to the beginning of the copied string.

Pay attention to that the explicit terminating zero character `'\0'` is redundant in the string literal.

The loop can look the following way

```
for ( char *src = "abcdef", *p = des; (*p++ = *src++););
```

And then after the loop

```
puts( des );
```

and

```
free( des );
```

You could write a separate function similar to `strcpy` the following way

```
char * my_strcpy( char *des, const char *src )
{
    for ( char *p = des; ( *p++ = *src++ ); );

    return des;
}
```

And call it like

```
puts( my_strcpy( des, "abcdef" ) )'
free( des );
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer, although there is no need to `free` to pointer at the end of the program, since that is the job of OS

Comment: @milanHrabos Well, he means it well, if your example would be part of a bigger program. In fact, there is no real-world program what will just copy a string to dynamic memory and print it. Vlad considered that and made it very good considered part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are incrementing `des` so naturally at the end of the cycle it will be pointing past the end of the string, printing it amounts to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/6865932), you have to bring it back to the beginning of `des`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int count = 0;
    char *des = malloc(10);

    if(des == NULL){
       return EXIT_FAILURE; //or otherwise handle the error
    }

    // '\0' is already added by the compiler so you don't need to do it yourself
    for(char *src="abcdef";(*des++ = *src++);){
        count++; //count the number of increments
    }
    des -= count + 1; //bring it back to the beginning
    printf("%s\n",des);
    free(dest); //to free the allocated memory when you're done with it
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or make a pointer to the beginning of `des` and print that instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
 
    char *des = malloc(10);

    if(des == NULL){
       return EXIT_FAILURE; //or otherwise handle the error
    }

    char *ptr = des;
    for(char *src="abcdef";(*des++ = *src++);){} //using {} instead of ;, it's clearer

    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    free(ptr) // or free(dest); to free the allocated memory when you're done with it
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: here `(*des++ = *src++)`, does have to be satisfy, but it is only satisfy - as long as - the value (address) is NOT `0`. But if your did not put the `\0` at the end of `*src`, then it will continue (read) infinity (or to crash). But is does not crash, so does it compiler for your? Does he put the '\0' null byte for you, at the end of the string?

Comment: but they were not. I think it is only from some version of compiler, does not you know what version?

Comment: @milanHrabos, yes `src` is null terminated by the compiler i.e. it puts a `'\0'` at the end of the string, all compilers do this, it's mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%s\n",des);` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as it attempts to print starting beyond the end of the string written to allocated memory.

**Copy the *string***

Save the original pointer, check it and free when done.

```
const char *src = "abcdef\0"; // string literal here has 2 ending `\0`, 
char *dest = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);  // 7

char *d = dest;
while (*d++ = *src++);
printf("%s\n", dest);
free(dest);
```

**Copy the *string literal***

```
const char src[] = "abcdef\0"; // string literal here has 2 ending `\0`, 
char *dest = malloc(sizeof src);  // 8

for (size_t i = 0; i<sizeof src; i++) {
  dest[i] = src[i];
}

printf("%s\n", dest);
free(dest);
```

Comment: You could use `while (*d++ = *p++);` in the second example too if you would assign the address of the first element of the array to a pointer `p`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio in the "Copy the string literal", `while (*d++ = *p++);` stops 1 too soon as the literal has 2 _null characters_.

Comment: Yes, but OP wants the string, not another redundant null character. I like pedantry but to transport his issue is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate the destination buffer `des` and correctly copy the source string into place. But since you are incrementing `des` for each character you copy, you have moved `des` from the start of the string to the end. When you go to print the result, you are printing the last byte which is the nil termination, which is empty.

Instead, you need to keep a pointer to the start of the string, as well as having a pointer to each character you copy.

The smallest change from your original source is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char *des = malloc(10);
    char *p = des;
    for(char *src="abcdef";(*p++ = *src++););
    printf("%s\n",des);
}
```

So `p` is the pointer to the next destination character, and moves along the string. But the final string that you print is `des`, from the start of the allocation.

Of course, you should also allocate `strlen(src)+1` worth of bytes for `des`. And it is not necessary to null-terminate a string literal, since that will be done for you by the compiler.

Comment: Is it possible to assign 3 vars? liek `char *p = *des = malloc(10)`?

Comment: "*The smallest change from your original source is*" - The smallest change is not always the best one.

Comment: Also you are saying that `des` would point to the NUL character which is wrong. It points one element past `NUL`.

Comment: "*Of course, you should also allocate `strlen(src)+1` worth of bytes for `des`.*" - While this brings a memory advantage, it is not necessary to do so. 10 `char`s will hold the string too. Also OP would need to place `char *src="abcdef"` before `char *des = malloc(10);` that way. You forgot to mention that.

Comment: "*But the final string that you print is `des`*" - Even if obvious, it may lead to confusion: `des` is a pointer, not a string.

Comment: "*You allocate the destination buffer `des` and correctly copy the source string into place.*" - `des` is not a buffer, you can't copy a string into it.

Comment: @milanHrabos "Is it possible to assign 3 vars? like `char *p = *des = malloc(10)`?" - Yes, but not in this way. F.e. `char* des, *p; p = des = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remember the original allocated pointer.

Do not program in main. Use **functions**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t strSpaceNeedeed(const char *str)
{
    const char *wrk = str;
    while(*wrk++);
    return wrk - str;
}

char *mystrdup(const char *str)
{
    char *wrk;
    char *dest = malloc(strSpaceNeedeed(str));

    if(dest)
    {
        for(wrk = dest; *wrk++ = *str++;);
    }   
    return dest;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", mystrdup("asdfgfd"));
}
```

or even better

```
size_t strSpaceNeedeed(const char *str)
{
    const char *wrk = str;
    while(*wrk++);
    return wrk - str;
}

char *mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *wrk = dest;
    while((*wrk++ = *src++)) ;
    return dest;
}

char *mystrdup(const char *str)
{
    char *wrk;
    char *dest = malloc(strSpaceNeedeed(str));

    if(dest)
    {
        mystrcpy(dest, str);
    }   
    return dest;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", mystrdup("asdfgfd"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But that prints nothing, and no error. What went wrong?

`des` does not point to the start of the string anymore after doing `(*des++ = *src++)`. In fact, `des` is pointing to one element past the `NUL` character, which terminates the string, thereafter.

Thus, if you want to print the string by using `printf("%s\n",des)` it invokes undefined behavior.

You need to store the address value of the "start" pointer (pointing at the first `char` object of the allocated memory chunk) into a temporary "holder" pointer. There are various ways possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    char *des = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    if (!des)
    {
        fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    char *tmp = des;

    for (const char *src = "abcdef"; (*des++ = *src++) ; );
    des = temp;

    printf("%s\n",des);

    free(des);
}
```

Alternatives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    char *des = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    if (!des)
    {
        fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    char *tmp = des;

    for (const char *src = "abcdef"; (*des++ = *src++) ; );

    printf("%s\n", tmp);

    free(tmp);
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    char *des = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    if (!des)
    {
        fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    char *tmp = des;

    for (const char *src = "abcdef"; (*tmp++ = *src++) ; );

    printf("%s\n", des);

    free(des);
}
```

---

Side notes:

- `"abcdef\0"` - The explicit `\0` is not needed. It is appended automatically during translation. Use `"abcdef"`.
- Always check the return of memory-management function if the allocation succeeded by checking the returned for a null pointer.
- Qualify pointers to string literal by `const` to avoid unintentional write attempts.
- Use `sizeof(char) * 10` instead of plain `10` in the call the malloc. This ensures the write size if the type changes.
- `int main (void)` instead of `int main (void)`. The first one is standard-compliant, the second not.
- Always `free()` dynamically allocated memory, since you no longer need the allocated memory. In the example above it would be redundant, but if your program becomes larger and the example is part-focused you should `free()` the unneeded memory immediately.

Comment: The OP did change the accepted answer, at least, to a better answer. Unfortunately, not to mine :/, well, we can't have it all.

Comment: @anastaciu In life crazy things happen. I sometimes see accepted answers to old questions that do not even address the question.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, the way it is, basically the OP can accept whatever, even plain wrong answers, itt's the nature of it. We can only rely on responsible users downvoting it, but that can always fail if no one is paying atention.

Comment: @anastaciu One example: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-and-c#comment6070653_93411) - This is the direct link to a comment regarding the concern the answer is misplaced.

Comment: @anastaciu The answer actually addressed the question title, but not the question.

Comment: Yep, you're right, the below answer  has a broken link, should we remove it?