# for loop: make increment and accessing in one loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I do not know why this is giving me garbage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a[10];
for(
    int i =0;
    i++<10;
    a[i-1]=i
   )
 {
  printf("%i:%i\n", i-1, a[i-1]);
 }
}
```

Which gives me:

```
0:1676584240
1:32609
2:0
3:0
4:-1577938528
5:21992
6:-1577938864
7:21992
8:2114427248
9:32766
```

The indices looks correct, and even the assignment inside the loop, is correct (e.g. `printf("%i\n",a[0])` gives `1` which is correct, after loop). But inside the body of for loop, the printf, despite having correct indices, gives wrong values (some garbage). Why is that?

EDIT, after some answers with `... && (a[i]=i)`, I have tried to do that with other statements:

```
for(
 int i = 0;
 i<10 && (a[i]=i);
 (i++) && printf("%i\n", a[i])
 );
```

But that does not print anything, just gives warning:

```
warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   i++ && printf("%i\n",a[i])
```

Why? when I can make "true" statement of `(a[i]=i)`, why cannot I make "true" statment of `(i++)`?

Comment: "gives wrong values" - what are the _correct_ values?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: are you aware of the fact that `a[ ]` is not initialized! so it hold some good garbage values !

Comment: you first print uninitialized value and only then assign a valid value to it.

Comment: you do `a[i-1]=i` **after** you printed it, so too late

Comment: But why, If I print after the loop for example `printf("%i\n",a[0])` get `1`?

Comment: @milanHrabos in`for(A;B;C){body]` the form C is done *after* the body execution, and you set each entry in C but print it in body

Comment: @bruno you right. So I have tried to give a value to `a[0]=1` before the loop (so initialize the first element, the rest gives the `i`) but to no avail

Comment: @milanHrabos also your code is 'complicated' because you increase *i* too earlier in the test part rather than in the C part

Comment: @milanHrabos I put an answer with a 'standard' way but also a way to not put the array initialization in the body of the `for` but I do not recommend to do that ^^

Comment: @bruno why is possible to treat assignment as "true" condition (after `&&`)?

Comment: @milanHrabos an assignment values the assigned value (out of a possible cast), so assigning 1 then 2 then 3 etc it is never 0 (suppose no overflow) so never false . look my answer for an other case

Comment: @milanHrabos read my answer and you will understand why `But that does not print anything`

Comment: @bruno, why is there always fight of whom to give the plus score? You all are experienced enough and have quite a lot of score but, still there are always the fights, I do not get it. The stackoverflow should give some solution to end this endless war. I will give it to you, but the reason was I was waiting to improve my own solution, which P__J__ did as first. But yes - you added that then as well. Ok, for this time

Comment: @bruno, I have only 50 points, but do not care. You have over 24k reputation, and still want more, so what is the point? What is the motivation of that? This does not make sense

Comment: @milanHrabos is both to play and also if you choose an answer that means the chosen is the 'best' => people writing other answers can agree with that (and sometime I UV other answer even I answer myself) or do not understand why, and consider is not 'fair'. Note you can also UV the other answer(s) to thank their author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doing

> ```
> for(
>     int i =0;
>     i++<10;
>     a[i-1]=i
>    )
>  {
>   printf("%i:%i\n", i-1, a[i-1]);
>  }
> ```

you set the entries *after* you print them because `a[i-1]=i` is executed *after* the body of the `for`, so you print non initialized array entries

your code is also 'complicated' because you increase *i* too earlier in the test part of `for`, a 'standard' way to do what you (probably) want is :

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); ++i) {
  a[i]=i+1;
  printf("%i:%i\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

if you really want to not have `a[i]=i+1;` in the body you can do that :

```
for(int i = 0; (i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) && (a[i]=i+1); ++i) {
  printf("%i:%i\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

to avoid a warning when compiling do `... && ((a[i]=i+1) != 0);`

note `(a[i]=i+1)` is not false because values at least 1, in case you wanted to do `a[i]=i` the test to use can be `(i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) && (a[i]=i, 1)` to not be false when *i* is 0

but that does not help to read the code ^^

Comment: see my edit please. I have changed the last expression in the head, but does not print anything. How to fix that?

Comment: @milanHrabos reread my answer where I say : note `(a[i]=i+1)` is not false because values at least 1, in case you wanted to do `a[i]=i` the test to use can be `(i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)) && (a[i]=i, 1)` to not be false when *i* is 0

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop consists of 4 parts:

1. Initialisation
2. Condition
3. Body code
4. Action

Example:

```
 for (initialisation; condition; action)
 {
     Body code
 }
```

The execution order is as I enumerated it above.

In your example,

```
for (int i = 0; i++ < 10; a[i-1])
{
    printf("%i:%i\n");
}
```

1. Initialisation - `i = 1`
2. Condition - `i++ < 10;` --> `0 < 10 = true`, `i = 1`
3. Body code - `printf` while `i=1`, `a[0]` is still **uninitialised**!
4. Action - `a[i-1] = i`, `a[0] = 1` (only now `a[0]` gets initialised!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you first execute the code in the brackets, then you assign the array. It has to be done the right opposite way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    for(int i =0; i++, i <= 10 && (a[i-1] = i);)
    {
        printf("%i:%i\n", i-1, a[i-1]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r-DvJi

or better

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 && (a[i] = i + 1); i++)
    {
        printf("%i:%i\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i++<10 && (a[i-1]=i); printf("%i\n",a[i-1]));` is the best option

Comment: did not know I can assign as "true" condition, it seems as a magic

Comment: @milanHrabos actually in the first (not existing in the answer) option I made a mistake. Generally it is an UB

Comment: see my edit. I have changed the last expression in for loop, but to no avail

Comment: i++ must go from the condition

Comment: why must? I cannot increment whenever I want? (And so at the end of the body loop, as from the thrid expression in the body loop)?