# How to use fscanf to read a line to parse into variables?

Tags: c, parsing, file-io, scanf

I'm trying to read a text file built with the following format in every line, for example:

```
a/a1.txt
a/b/b1.txt
a/b/c/d/f/d1.txt
```

Using `fscanf` to read a line from file, how can you automatically parse the line into the variables of `*element` and `*next`, with each element being a path section (`a`, `a1.txt`, `b`, `c`, `d1.txt` and so on).

My structure is as follows:

```
struct MyPath {
    char *element;  // Pointer to the string of one part.
    MyPath *next;   // Pointer to the next part - NULL if none.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using `fgets` to read the entire line into memory, then `strtok` to tokenise the line into individual elements.

The following code shows one way to do this. First, the headers and structure definintion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct sMyPath {
    char *element;
    struct sMyPath *next;
} tMyPath;
```

Then, the main function, initially creating an empty list, then getting input from user (if you want a robust input function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921), what follows below is a cut down version of that for demonstrative purposes only):

```
int main(void) {
    char *token;
    tMyPath *curr, *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
    char inputStr[1024];

    // Get a string from the user (removing newline at end).

    printf ("Enter your string: ");
    fgets (inputStr, sizeof (inputStr), stdin);
    if (strlen (inputStr) > 0)
        if (inputStr[strlen (inputStr) - 1] == '\n')
            inputStr[strlen (inputStr) - 1] = '\0';
```

Then the code to extract all tokens and add them to a linked list.

```
    // Collect all tokens into list.

    token = strtok (inputStr, "/");
    while (token != NULL) {
        if (last == NULL) {
            first = last = malloc (sizeof (*first));
            first->element = strdup (token);
            first->next = NULL;
        } else {
            last->next = malloc (sizeof (*last));
            last = last->next;
            last->element = strdup (token);
            last->next = NULL;
        }
        token = strtok (NULL, "/");
    }
```

(keeping in mind that `strdup` is not standard C but you can always find [a decent implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802) somewhere). Then we print out the linked list to show it was loaded properly, followed by cleanup and exit:

```
    // Output list.

    for (curr = first; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        printf ("[%s]\n", curr->element);

    // Delete list and exit.

    while (first != NULL) {
        curr = first;
        first = first->next;
        free (curr->element);
        free (curr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A sample run follows:

```
Enter your string: path/to/your/file.txt
[path]
[to]
[your]
[file.txt]
```

---

I should mention also that, while C++ allows you to leave off the `struct` keyword from structures, C does not. Your definition should be:

```
struct MyPath {
    char *element;         // Pointer to the string of one part.
    struct MyPath *next;   // Pointer to the next part - NULL if none.
};
```