# How to perform a deep copy of a char *?

Tags: c++

I'm a little confused on how to perform a deep copy a of a char *. This is what I have:

```
Appointment(Appointment& a)
{
  subject = new char;
  *subject = *(a.subject);
}

Appointment(Appointment& b)
{
  location = new char;
  *location = *(b.location);
}

char *subject;
char *location;
```

I'm trying to perform a deep copy of the char pointers subject and location. Will this work? If not, any advice on how to go about doing this?

Comment: you need the length of those strings and std::copy. Or avoid char* and use std::string which can take care of itself when copying.

Comment: If you have an array at the memory location, you may want to not use `new char`, since this only allocates enough memory for 1 char, so you'd be running into [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you try to access the rest of the array (meaning it may work, but not necessarily all the time). You need to instead say `new char[len]`.

Comment: And you have two identically-parameterized semi-conforming copy-ctors. This code won't even *compile* as-is, much less be correct. You need *a* singular conforming copy-ctor (make the argument a const reference) that initializes *both* members correctly, or better still, use `std::string` and make all this utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using C++ you should be using `std::string` for your string needs.

The following code you wrote

```
Appointment(Appointment& a)
{
  subject = new char;
  *subject = *(a.subject);
}
```

will not do what you think it will do, above you allocate one character (`new char`) then assign the first character of `a.subject` to it (`*subject = *(a.subject)`)

In order to copy the string that `char*` points to you must first determine the string length, allocate memory to hold the string and then copy the characters.

```
Appointment(Appointment& a)
{
  size_t len = strlen(a.subject)+1;
  subject = new char [len]; // allocate for string and ending \0
  strcpy_s(subject,len,a.subject);
}
```

an alternative way to `char*` would be to use a `std::vector<char>`, it depends on what you want to do with the string.

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `strdup`. Since it is using `malloc` internally do not forget to call `free` in the destructor.

See:

- [strdup manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)
- [function - strdup() - what does it do in C? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of the `char*` lengths in order to make copies of them, eg:

```
class Appointment
{
public:
    char *subject;
    int subject_len;

    char *location;
    int location_len;

    Appointment() :
        subject(NULL), subject_len(0),
        location(NULL), location_len(0)
    {
    }

    ~Appointment()
    {
        delete[] subject;
        delete[] location;
    }

    Appointment(const Appointment& src) :
        subject(new char[src.subject_len]), subject_len(src.subject_len),
        location(new char[src.location_len]), location_len(src.location_len)
    {
        std::copy(src.subject, src.subject + src.subject_len, subject);
        std::copy(src.location, src.location + src.location_len, location);
    }

    Appointment& operator=(const Appointment& lhs)
    {
        delete[] subject;
        subject = NULL;

        delete[] location;
        location = NULL;

        subject = new char[lhs.subject_len];
        subject_len = lhs.subject_len;
        std::copy(lhs.subject, lhs.subject + lhs.subject_len, subject);

        location = new char[lhs.location_len];
        location_len = lhs.location_len;
        std::copy(lhs.location, lhs.location + lhs.location_len, location);
    }
};
```

In which case, you are better off using `std::string` instead:

```
class Appointment
{
public:
    std::string subject;
    std::string location;

    Appointment()
    {
    }

    Appointment(const Appointment& src) :
        subject(src.subject), location(src.location)
    {
    }

    Appointment& operator=(const Appointment& lhs)
    {
        subject = lhs.subject;
        location = lhs.location;
    }
};
```

Which can be simplified further, as the default constructors and assignment operator generated by the compiler are sufficient to deep-copy the values for you automatically:

```
class Appointment
{
public:
    std::string subject;
    std::string location;
};
```

Comment: +1 for the hopefully self-evident testimonial on why intelligent members  are a *good thing*. Nice step-wise summary.

Answer (score 0):

no.

you need to allocate enough memory to store the string you want to copy

```
subject = new char [strlen(a.subject + 1]; // +1 to allow for null charcter terminating the string.
```

then use `strncpy` `memcpy` or copy all the characters in a loop to copy the string