# How to initialize a char array using a char pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

Let's say I have a char pointer called string1 that points to the first character in the word "hahahaha". I want to create a char[] that contains the same string that string1 points to.

How come this does not work?

```
char string2[] = string1;
```

Comment: There's an assumption implicit in the question that arrays and pointers are the same thing in C (trying to initialize a new array of `char` by reference to a `char*` pointer). This is *not* the case and it's important to understand the differences to avoid introducing subtle bugs into your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "How come this does not work?"

Because that's not how the C language was defined.

You can create a copy using `strdup()` [Note that `strdup()` is not ANSI C]

Refs:

- [C string handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strdup#strdup)
- [strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

1) pointer string2 == pointer string1

change in value of either will change the other

From poster poida

```
char string1[] = "hahahahaha";
char* string2 = string1;
```

2) Make a Copy

```
char string1[] = "hahahahaha";
char string2[11]; /* allocate sufficient memory plus null character */
strcpy(string2, string1);
```

change in value of one of them will not change the other

Answer (score 0):

What you write like this:

```
char str[] =  "hello";
```

... actually becomes this:

```
char str[] =  {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

Here we are implicitly invoking something called the **initializer**.
Initializer is responsible for making the character array, in the above scenario.
Initializer does this, behind the scene:

```
char str[5];

str[0] = 'h';
str[1] = 'e';
str[2] = 'l';
str[3] = 'l';
str[4] = 'o';
```

---

C is a very low level language. Your statement:

```
char str[] = another_str;
```

doesn't make sense to C. 
It is not possible to **assign** an entire array, to another in C. You have to copy letter  by letter, either manually or using the strcpy() function.
In the above statement, the initializer does not know the length of the `another_str` array variable. If you hard code the string instead of putting `another_str`, then it will work.

Some other languages might allow to do such things... but you can't expect a manual car to switch gears automatically. You are in charge of it.

Comment: It ACTUALLY becomes char str[] =  {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}; Every string literal has an implicit '\0' attached to the end of it.

Answer (score -1):

In **C** you have to reserve memory to hold a string.
This is done automatically when you define a constant string, and then assign to a char[].

On the other hand, when you write `string2 = string1`,
what you are actually doing is assigning the memory addresses of **pointer-to-char** objects.  If `string2` is declares as `char*` (pointer-to-char), then it is valid the assignment:

```
char* string2 = "Hello.";
```

The variable `string2` now holds the address of the first character of the constanta array of char "Hello.".

It is fine, also, to write string2 = string1 when `string2` is a `char*` and `string1` is a `char[]`.

However, it is supposed that a `char[]` has constant address in memory. Is not modifiable.
So, it is not allowed to write sentences like that:

```
 char string2[];
 string2 = (something...);
```

However, you are able to modify the individual characters of string2, because is an array of characters:

```
 string2[0] = 'x'; /* That's ok! */
```