# C - A simple shell on linux - Some trouble with commands

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I wrote this simple shell so far. But I got some trouble with my shell.
For example, when I try to open a pdf file via the command "evince pdffile.pdf", the actual pdfile does not get opened. The pdf viewer runs but the actual file with the whole content never appears.
Or another example is the command "ls -l". I don't get the files and folders listed as it should be, but "ls" is working.
Another example is gedit, and so on.
Also, I should mention. I am not using "system()", because system() would do everything and I would not have something to do. Instead, I am using "execvp()".
Here is the code. I hope, you may find the problem, because I have no clue what the problem is causing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"

void exec_cmd (char *buf);

int main() {    
   char line[MAX_LENGTH];
   char * cmd;
   char curDir[100];

   while (1) {  
       getcwd(curDir, 100);
       printf("%s@%s$ ", getlogin(), curDir);
       if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin))
           break;

       if ((cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS))) {
           errno = 0;
           if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0) {
              char *arg = strtok(0, DELIMS);

              if (!arg) 
                 fprintf(stderr, "cd: argument is missing.\n");
              else chdir(arg);

           } else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
                 exit(0);

           } else exec_cmd(line);

        if (errno) perror("Error. Command failure");
        }
   }
return 0;
}

void exec_cmd (char *buf) {
    int status = 0;
    char *argv[MAX_LENGTH];
    int j=0;
    pid_t pid;
    argv[j++] = strtok (buf, DELIMS);
    while (j<MAX_LENGTH && (argv[j++]=strtok(NULL,DELIMS))!=NULL); // EDIT: " " replaced by DELIMS 

    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
       printf("Error occured");
       exit(-1);
    } else if(pid == 0) {
         execvp(argv[0],argv);
    } else if( pid > 0) {
         wait(&status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the arguments (eg, print them out, each enclosed in `[]`) before you call `fork/exec`, there's a good chance they're *not* what you think.

While your first call to `strtok` uses your full delimiter set, subsequent calls do not. They instead just use a space. That means that the final argument will probably have the newline left on the string by `fgets`. I'd be using the same delimiter set in the subsequent calls. In other words:

```
while (j<MAX_LENGTH && (argv[j++]=strtok(NULL,DELIMS))!=NULL);
```

Having entered your code and done that debugging, I find that the string passed to the function only ever has one word in it. It turns out that's because of the `strtok` that happened in `main` to check for `cd/exit`. That left the nul character at the end of the first word, an effect inherent in the way `strtok` works.

Probably the quickest fix is to make a copy of the string *before* the initial `strtok` in main, then pass *that* to the function. In other words, use `strdup` (and, later, `free`). Now glibc *has* a `strdup` but, if you're in an environment that doesn't (it's POSIX rather than ISO), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the last strtok. I corrected this mistake, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @user2965601: and, when you printed out the args, what did you see? Both before and after the fix. That's the crux of the answer, the best wat to debug what the actual problem is.

Comment: I copied the content of line[] in another array with a while loop.
It seems to be working. Should I still use strdup?

Comment: @user2965601, yes, you should. You should generally prefer using language features to coding your own. You'll deliver your software a lot faster that way :-)

Comment: I did it as you said. Also, thank you for your help. It helped a lot. :)

Comment: I have another question. I don't know if it's ok to ask another question here, but I just go ahead and will ask you. You tell me, if it is not ok.
I just tried to add an extra feature to my shell. It should return the running time of an program. I used clock(). I put "start = clock()" before execvp() and "end = clock()" after wait(&status).
But it seems not to be working. Also, I'd like to have it formatted like hh:mm:ss.
Do you know if it is there a clever way to do that?

Comment: @user2965601, would get more visibility as separate question but I'll help out. 1/ clock() gives cpu time, not elapsed time. That may be < elapsed if child sleeps or > elapsed if child has many threads. `gettimeofday` may be better. 2/ You should set start before the fork rather than exec since you want to do all this in the parent. As to hh.mm.ss, best way is to probably just use division/modulo with 60. That's about as much detail as will fit in a comment, so you may want to ask a couple more questions. That's how SO works best.

Comment: I will try your suggestion out. If I fail, I'll ask it as a separate question. Would it be ok a reference to this question or shall I put the whole code online again?

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in `main()`.

You are using `strtok` to find the first word of the line. But `strtok` modifies the line, making it actually contain just that word (a NUL terminator is written to the string right after it).

You need to make a copy of the line, or use `strtok_s`, or do something else to avoid modifying the line.

Comment: To be clear if "line" contains "hello world", when you strtok line it will become "hello\0world" so when you pass line to exec_cmd it is interpreted as a string containing just "hello".

Comment: You are right. This was causing the problem. I would not have seen that without you, guys.
Thank you! :)

Comment: @Duck: Right before, I tried to print it out, but it did not work. Could you maybe show me how to print it correctly?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to print.  `printf("%s\n",line);` before and after the `strtok` to see this.

Comment: Or better, `printf("[%s]\n",line);` so you can see extraneous newlines easier.