# strcpy() with copying string from one structure to another

Tags: c, struct, strcpy

it seems that this is a duplicate question, but I searched stackoverflow's question about that point and non is like to my problem(I think)

I've two variables of a struct each has its own pointer to char, when I tried to copy from one variable's string to another variable's string, nothing happened, although no errors appear, just warning

```
implicit declaration of function strcpy
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy'
```

I read from some questions on stackoverflow that you'd better to use strdup() function instead of strcpy() but when I did, I had an error

```
too many arguments to function 'strdup'
```

I read that there's a problem with strcpy() called "segmentation fault" and I knew it's about memory allocation, I don't totally understand what it's exactly and don't know if it's the problem with my code?

and this is  my code

```
struct p
{
char *name;
struct p *next;
};
struct p *ptrary[10];

int main(void)
{
    struct p p,q;
    p.name="xyz";
    p.next=NULL;
    ptrary[0]=&p;

    strdup(q.name,p.name);
    ptrary[1]=&q;

    printf("%s\n",ptrary[1]->name);
return 0;
}
```

so what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: Add `#include <string.h>` before the rest of the code (and make sure it's on a line by itself). `strdup` isn't standard, but typical usage would be like: `q.name = strdup(p.name);`.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for the functions? I'll bet anything it tells you what header files you have to include to use them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin q.name=strdup(p.name); worked with me without including new library

Comment: @Salahuddin: You should still almost certainly include `<string.h>` (or whatever header declares `strdup` on your system).

Comment: When you see "implicit declaration" you should treat it as an error. It doesn''t matter if it happens to work, just go back and fix things until this message does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

strdup() takes only one argument; it malloc's and returns a new block of heap memory containing the duplicated string. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Which probably also points to the problem you were having before -- were you remembering to malloc the space for q to copy p's contents into?

Answer (score 1):

change

> ```
> strdup(q.name,p.name);
> ```

to

> ```
> q.name = strdup(p.name);
> ```

[see man page of strdup for further details](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup). The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string.

full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct p
{
  char *name;
  struct p *next;
};
struct p *ptrary[10];

int main(void)
{
struct p p,q;
p.name="xyz";
p.next=NULL;
ptrary[0]=&p;

q.name = strdup(p.name);
ptrary[1]=&q;

printf("%s\n",ptrary[1]->name);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, it worked with me, but was the problem with strcpy?

Comment: Why strcpy doesn't do the job?

Comment: malloc the `q.name` and then use `strcpy`

Comment: so strcpy() needs the memory locations to be initialized. right?