# Why isn't fscanf() storing this string in this pointer?

Tags: c, string, scanf

Ok, so I am having trouble reading in the string names and storing them in my struct array of type student. The age field is an int and the gpa field is a double and those worked fine. Then when I added the name to be read I started running into issues. How can I successfully read in a name and store it in the student.name field? The code below crashes and I am not sure why. I am new in C so please tell me if there is a better way to do this. Thank you in advance. Oh and the name is consecutive letters with no spaces between characters.

```
typedef struct student{
     char *name; int age; double gpa;
}student; 

void read(char *filename) {
File *file = fopen(filename,"r");  
if(!file) return; 
student *students = malloc(sizeof(student)*100); 
int num_students = 10; //for example
int i; 
for (i=0;i<num_students;i++) {

    char *n = malloc(MAXLENGTH); 
    fscanf(file,"%s %i %lf", n,&students[i].age,&students[i].gpa); //<---runtime error occurs here
    strcpy(students[i].name,n);
    free(n);
} 

/*code here to do stuff with the array*/
free(students); 
fclosef(file); 
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of the "student" structure, and what the "crash" error is, and on what line.  We are not mind readers. Also, where is num_students defined and assigned a value?  Please show **complete** code examples.

Comment: Are there any spaces in the names? Does the student structure have a built-in array, or just a char pointer?

Comment: You have not allocated memory to `students[i].name` array

Comment: Also: Be sure to check the return value of `fscanf()`.  `if (3 != fscanf(...)) Handle_Errror();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n =0;
for (i=0;i<num_students;i++) {

char *n = malloc(MAXLENGTH); 
n = fscanf(file,"%s %i %lf", n,&students[i].age,&students[i].gpa);
if(n!= 3 || n = EOF){
    printf("invald input..");
}
students[i].name = malloc(strlen(n) +1);
if(student[i].name != NULL){
    strcpy(students[i].name,n);
}
free(n);
}
```

man fscanf

Upon successful completion, these functions return the number of successfully matched 
and     assigned input items; this number can be 0 in the event of an early matching 
failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF is 
returned. If a read error occurs the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF is
returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Comment: Yes I forgot to malloc the student.name field for each element in the array. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line `strcpy(students[i].name,n);` with `students[i].name = strdup(n);`

I use `strdup` to allocate enough memory to hold the string, if you tried `=` it will work but will make `name` as read only! `strcpy()` will work too
Here you are reference for strdup use: [strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Also I don't see you allocating memory for `students[i].name`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the "string" into the file that you want to store into n array does not have null terminator. So %s does not work fine into the fscanf(). Try another option to that, as treat it as a cvs file.