# memory free throws segFault

Tags: c, malloc

I am implementing symbol table using link list, The code works fine but there is memory leak in code,

I have following structure

> ```
> struct node
> {
>   char* pcKey;
>   void* pvValue;
>   struct node *next;
> };
>
> struct _Sym
> {
>   int totalBindings;
>   struct node *node;
> };
> ```

add I have sym_new method to allocate memory for sym instance

```
sym Sym_new (void)
{
    _Sym *m_SymTable_t = (_Sym*) malloc (sizeof(_Sym));

    if(m_SymTable_t == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        m_SymTable_t->totalBindings = 0;
        m_SymTable_t->node = NULL;
        return m_SymTable_t;
    }//endif
}
```

I am allocating memory for key and value in other function based on the string length.

The free method is

```
typedef struct _Sym *Sym;

void Sym_free (Sym m_SymTable_t)
{
    assert(m_SymTable_t != NULL);

    struct node* temp = m_SymTable_t->node;

    struct node *currentBinding = NULL;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        currentBinding = temp;
        temp = temp -> next;

            //Removing comment for the below line throws segfault
        //free(currentBinding -> pcKey);
        //free(currentBinding -> pvValue);

        free(currentBinding);
    }

    free(m_SymTable_t);
}
```

What is proper way to free the sym completely?

I have uploaded my symTable_Link.cpp file at link

Comment: It looks like you didn't initialize pcKey and pvValue to NULL in the allocator function?

Comment: Also useful may be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc - why not to cast return of `malloc`. It's not what's wrong with the code... just a comment

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for pcKey and pvValue?  Also, *please* don't use Hungarian notation to encode primitive type information in the variable name; that's not what it's meant for.

Comment: I am allocating memory for pcKey and PcVal in another function called sym_put

Comment: Do you always call `sym_put()` for each entry? If not you should initialise the pointers to `null` in the `Sym_new` function. `free()` will ignore `null` pointers but will segfault on dangling pointers or pointers that contain junk - the `malloc`ed memory is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Is it possible that you deallocate your _Sym before allocating memory for `pcKey` and `pcVal`?

Comment: @Jimbo Yes, sym_put is called fot each new binding.

Comment: @Sagar, could you check? Initialise the pointers with say, 0xdeadbeaf, and then in your `sym_free` function check for this magic number... if it is found it indicates the a `sym_put` got missed...

Comment: @Jarhmander No, _sym is freed only in Sym_free that to at last.

Comment: I have uploaded my symTable_Link.cpp file at [link](http://tempsend.com/62CCDBF79A)

Comment: When I free a pointer, I usually set it explicitly to NULL afterwards. That way you don't accidentally free it twice. Note also in your linked code you do `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(pcKey))` - you need `malloc(sizeof(char) *(strlen(pcKey) + 1))` to account for terminating `'\0'`. And I think `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, but that doesn't mean it's wrong to be explicit about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `pcKey` and `pvValue` should probably be initialised to `null` in the `Sym_new()` function. Otherwise they may contain any old value. This is because `malloc` doesn't necessarily zero the memory allocated: it just allocates a chunk of memory and the memory could therefore be filled with junk.

So, if for some reason `sym_put()` is not called for the newly created object these pointers could point to invalid memory and upon your call to `free()` segfault. If you initialise them to `null` `free()` will just ignore them and won't try to free the memory.

A "hacky" *DEBUG-only* technique you could use to check that the `pcKey` and `pvValue` variables are definitely allocated by a `sym_put` call would be to initialise them in `sym_new` with a dummy value, for example 0xCDCDCDCD (careful about pointer-widths here... this is why I'm calling this a hacky technique). Then in `sym_free` check for this magic constant before freeing `pcKey` and `pvValue`. If you find it, there's the problem...

Also of interest may be the thread [***Do I cast the result of malloc?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

EDIT:

Looked at the code linked and you appear to be **discarding const**!

The function id defined as:

```
int SymTable_put (SymTable_t m_SymTable_t, const char *pcKey, const void *pvValue)
```

But then does this cast...

```
temp->pcKey = (char*)pcKey;
temp->pvValue = (char*)pvValue;
```

This is a bad idea. You're "fooling" the compiler into invalidating your const promise.

**THE BUG:**
Ok, so you allocate as follows

```
temp->pcKey = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen (pcKey));
```

But then you overwrite this pointer using

```
temp->pcKey = (char*)pcKey;
```

So you a) have a memory leak and b) have just stashed the wrong pointer, which is probs why you get the segfault. You you probably meant to do instead is ([***strdup***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c) is useful here)...

```
temp->pcKey = strdup(pcKey);
```

This will allocate new memory for the string in `pcKey` and **COPY** the string into the new memory.

I would hazzard a guess you called the function like this...

```
SymTable_put (xxx, "KEY string", "VALUE string");
```

Then your code did this

```
temp->pcKey = (char*)malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen (pcKey));
...
temp->pcKey = (char*)pcKey;
```

So now `temp->pcKey` points to "KEY string" itself and *not* a copy of it. So when you try to free the string constant, your program complains. What you want to do is *copy* the string from `pcKey` into `temp->pcKey` instead of overwriting the pointer.

EDIT:
As per comments the `malloc`s need space + 1 to include the null terminator. Also `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so is redundant. Try `strdup` instread.

Comment: i can see valid addresses for pcKey and pvValue, the exact implementation http://tempsend.com/62CCDBF79A

Comment: You need to `malloc` for `strlen + 1` - don't forget the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: Yep good point, I didn't spot that. +1 `strdup` will solve that problem by doing the allocate and copy in one go...