# Patial copy of string array

Tags: c, linux, string, copy

Can I do something like this, to copy string array content from one to another?

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * lines_allocated); 
char **childWords = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * len1); 
int i;
for(i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    childWords[i] = words[i];       
}
```

Comment: You are copying the pointers to the string, not the strings themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is duplicating the pointers to the lines of text, so that you will end up with two arrays of char*'s which point to the same physical memory containing the actual words.

The problem with this is that if you change the memory through 'words' then 'childWords' would change because they point to the same memory.

The safest way to do this would be to get the string length of each 'word' and allocate new memory, copying the string over so that 'childWords' points to different memory.

Comment: Do I need to allocate new memory for each "word", allocating "childWord" from the beginning wouldn't be the same?

Comment: You would need to allocate new memory for "childWord[i]" based on length word[i]. E.G. childWord[i] = new char[strlen(word[i])+1]; This creates a new piece of memory the same size as the original word[i] and childWord[i] now points to it. Now you can copy  original word[i] into this new childWord[i] using memcpy/strcpy/or whatever other method you choose.

Answer (score 3):

You are copying pointers to the strings, not the strings themselves. You should change your `for` loop to

```
for(i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    childWords[i] = strdup(words[i]);  // creates a new copy of the string       
}
```

`strdup` duplicates the string by allocating enough memory to copy the string passed to it, i.e., it returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string pointed to by `words[i]`. The pointer can be passed to `free`. It's declared in the `string.h` header file.

Please note that you should not cast the result of `malloc`. There's no benefit and it can lead to bugs if you forget to include the `stdlib.h` header file. Also `strdup` is a part of the POSIX standard and under the hood, it effectively does the same thing as `malloc` and then `strcpy`. Read more here [What does strdup do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252802/1809377)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `memcpy()` or `bcopy()` instead?
Also, I don't believe you need to cast the result from `malloc()`.