# Making a pyramid in C

Tags: c, loops, substring

I have to make a pyramid only using C, no C++. what I have to do is this,
I have a string "this is a string " (yes the space is suppose to be there), and I have to "remove" one letter from both sides, and print that. like this

```
"this is a string "
 "his is a string"
  "is a strin"
   "s a stri"
    " a str"
```

This is repeated until there are no more characters. My teacher says to use substrings, is there any thing in C that says

> print from location (index 0 to index x) 
>   print from location (index 1 to index x-1)

I know I have to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a question.  What have you tried so far?  Nobody here is going to hold your hand and write all your code for you.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It's very much a beginner-level question, but nowhere is he asking for the code to be written for him.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yea i wasnt asking for the code, shouldve put that in the question :( but I got as far as writing a for loop down lol. been banging my head since 2pm today

Comment: Why not replace characters at each with space. Then you just print the line again. Then you don't have to worry about ligning it up each time.

Comment: @LokiAstari i would if i could :P i looked everywhere and cant figure out how to do it. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is homework, so I'll just get you started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char src[] = "this is a test string";
    char dest[5] = {0}; // 4 chars + terminator
    for (int i = 0; i * 4 < strlen(src); i++) {
        strncpy(dest, src+(i*4), 4);
        puts(dest);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
this
 is 
a te
st s
trin
g
```

So for your pyramid problem, you will want to take the substring of the your original string. Set the beginning of your substring one character ahead of your original string, and `strlen(original) - 1` for the end character.  Then loop that process.

Comment: oh my gosh, i think with this i can figure it out! thank you so much!!!!! i just needed that kick in the right direction

Comment: since when is `strdup()` part of the standard?

Comment: @Deduplicator Ever since I didn't want to do manual memory management.

Comment: There's someone going around here downvoting everything. Got me too... BTW: Of course it's also in my bag of tools. Still non-standard though.

Comment: i didnt downvote :( i cant even vote yet..and ill upvote as soon as i can!

Comment: `char* substr;
    strncpy(substr, buff+10, 4);` : can't copy,,

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Clearly you haven't run the program, because it can.

Comment: So, to where you are copying? without '\0'.

Comment: To nirvana, where else ;-) UB greets you all.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY There, fixed.

Comment: Still UB, buffer overrun.

Comment: `strdup()` is specified by [POSIX, but not standard C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/252782/1157100).

Comment: @StevenR You should now have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: @syb0rg I'm quite sure `strncpy()` does not allocate any memory. It's easy enough to test. Running your program w/ valgrind gets me `Invalid write of size 1 at 0x4C2DA5C: strncpy`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a printing facility enabling you to print substrings. Read the spec for `printf`.

There is a way to give it a parameter (int) which limits how many characters from another parameter (char*) it prints.

Answer (score 1):

To chop off the first character of a string, simply treat the next character as the start of the string.  So, instead of `puts(str)`, call `puts(str + 1)`.

To chop off the last character of a string, overwrite the last character with a `\0` character.  Since this is a destructive operation, it is probably a good idea to operate a copy of the original string.

To solve this problem, then, make a copy of the string.  Keep two pointers: one at the front of the copied string walking towards the end, and one at the end walking towards the front.

Comment: I just started learning C like yesterday, how will i go about overwriting the last character with \0 ? and i already have a copy of the string, so im good to destroy it :)

Comment: `str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0'`

Comment: hmph, im getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error

Comment: The technique is sound, I assure you. Start with small steps: 1) Print the whole string.  2) Print a copy of the string.  3) Print it without the first character.  4) Print it without the last character.  5) Write the pyramid loop.

Comment: im getting the segmentation error when doing the overwrite method, I got up to removing the first letter.

Comment: Would you like to post your code? I suggest a separate question, referencing this one, since your question is now about debugging a segfault.

Comment: hm, dont know how without it going all into 2 lines, ill just ask another question.

Comment: @StevenR: Overwriting only works if the string is writable. Generally not the case with string-literals.