# Segmentation Fault in C, substring

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got help with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22775107/1157100), and one of the answers suggested this technique, but i keep getting a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error in this the code.

```
char *nam = array;//<-----(array is a string, we can use "test string" for it
int i = 0;
int length = strlen(array);
int count = 1;
printf("%i [%s]\n", length,nam);    
for(i; i < length; i++)
{
    puts(nam + i);
    nam[strlen(nam) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

What's supposed to happen, is I'm supposed to make a pyramid with the string, by removing one letter from the front, and one letter from the back. With this code, I managed to get rid of one letter from the front, but the error occurs on the "replacing" the last letter with a '\0'.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT------------(updated code for clarification)

```
void pyramid(char array[])
{    
char nam[] = array;
int i = 0;
int length = strlen(nam);
int count = 1;
printf("%i [%s]\n", length, nam);   
for(i; i < length; i++)
{
    puts(nam + i);
    nam[strlen(nam) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("[%s]\n", nam);
}
}
```

main class

```
int main (void)
{
    char *name = "TEST STRING";
    pyramid(name);
}
```

hope this clarifies
this code gives me an invalid initializer on the char[] = array; line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array` is a string literal, you should not try to change it.

Change

```
char *nam = array;
```

to

```
char nam[] = array;
```

and try again.

By the way, the actual code should be look like

```
char name[] = "test string";
```

---

UPDATE:

Version 1, need C99 VLA

```
void pyramid(char array[])
{    
    int length = strlen(array);
    char nam[length+1];
    int i = 0;
    int count = 1;

    strcpy(nam, array);
    printf("%i [%s]\n", length, nam);   
    for(i; i < length; i++)
    {
        puts(nam + i);
        nam[strlen(nam) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("[%s]\n", nam);
    }
}
```

Version 2, use dynamical memory allocation:

```
void pyramid(char array[])
{    
    char *nam;
    int i = 0;
    int length = strlen(array);
    int count = 1;

    if ((nam = malloc(length+1)) == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(nam, array);

    printf("%i [%s]\n", length, nam);   
    for(i; i < length; i++)
    {
        puts(nam + i);
        nam[strlen(nam) - 1] = '\0';
        printf("[%s]\n", nam);
    }

    free(nam);
}
```

Comment: @StevenR The actual code should be look like `char name[] = "teststring";`.

Comment: i actually updated my code on top for more clarification of what im trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *nam = array;//<-----(array is a string, we can use "test string" for it
```

you cann't modify the variable `name`, because of `"test string"` is allocated in character constant region, so you cann't modify it.

please use `char nam[] = "test string".`, in this case `"test string"` is allocated in stack, so you can modify it.

Comment: oh i see, well it works now, but what i did was i called a method in the main class with the actual string, and this method is supposed to obtain the name, so how do i go about doing that? im going to re-edit my original so you see what im talking about

Answer (score 1):

A string literal is stored in a read-only memory segment.  You should consider it a `const char *`, or immutable string.

If you are writing a function to perform a destructive operation on a string, it is good practice to make a copy of it anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void pyramid_demo(const char *input) {
    /* Copy input to buf */
    int len = strlen(input);
    char *buf = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(buf, input);

    puts(buf);
    buf[len - 1] = '\0';    /* Now you can write to buf */
    puts(buf + 1);
}

int main(void) {
    /* The literal string is immutable */
    pyramid_demo("Hello world");
}
```

---

#### Critique of your `pyramid()` function

Aside from the segfault, there are other problems with your `pyramid()` function:

- `count` is an unused variable.
- In `for(i`, the `i` is useless.  If you are using C99 or newer, you should delete the existing declaration/initialization of `i`, and write instead:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  ```
- `char nam[] = array;` is pointless aliasing.  It doesn't make a copy of the input.
- Avoid calling `strlen()` repeatedly, since each call requires walking down the entire string to look for the `\0` terminator.  You already set `length` at the beginning, so just keep track of the string length by decrementing `length`.

Comment: noobie mistakes, i know :( i just wish my teacher actually TAUGHT us this instead he just talks about real world stuff, and doesnt teach, thank you for your help

Comment: Please indicate you appreciation by voting up useful answers instead of commenting.  Your votes are what make Stack Overflow work.

Comment: oh woops! forgot to do that!