# insertion doesn't take place for bigger size strings

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures

Below programme doesn’t work for bigger size strings , but it works properly for small strings.I am not sure why sortedInsert function is not taking full length of string.There is no string length constraint also being used in this programme.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<string.h>

/* Link list node */

struct node

{

    char* pattern;

    struct node* next;

};

/* function to insert a new_node in a list. Note that this

*   function expects a pointer to head_ref as this can modify the

*     head of the input linked list (similar to push())*/

void sortedInsert(struct node** head_ref, struct node* new_node)

{

    struct node* current;

    /* Special case for the head end */

    if (*head_ref == NULL || (strcmp((*head_ref)->pattern ,new_node->pattern)> 0))

    {

        new_node->next = *head_ref;

        *head_ref = new_node;

    }

    else

    {

        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */

        current = *head_ref;

        while (current->next!=NULL &&

               strcmp(current->next->pattern, new_node->pattern)< 0)

        {

            current = current->next;

        }

        new_node->next = current->next;

        current->next = new_node;

    }

}

/* BELOW FUNCTIONS ARE JUST UTILITY TO TEST sortedInsert */

/* A utility function to create a new node */

struct node *newNode( char * pattern)

{

    /* allocate node */

    struct node* new_node =

        (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

      new_node->pattern = (char *)malloc(sizeof(pattern));

    /* put in the data  */

    strcpy(new_node->pattern , pattern);



    new_node->next =  NULL;

    return new_node;

}

/* Function to print linked list */

void printList(struct node *head)

{





   struct node *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)

    { 

         printf("\n%s", temp->pattern);

        temp = temp->next;

    }

}

/* Drier program to test count function*/

int main()

{

    /* Start with the empty list */

    struct node* head = NULL;

    struct node* new_node = newNode("a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.h.j.k.l.m.n.o");

    sortedInsert(&head, new_node);

    new_node = newNode("a.b.c.de.f.g.h.j.k.l.m.t.y.u.k");

    sortedInsert(&head, new_node);

    new_node = newNode("a.b.c.d.ef.g.h.h.k.j.l.y.u.l.p");

    sortedInsert(&head, new_node);

    printf("\n Created Linked List\n");

    printList(head);



    return 0;

}
```

Here is the output of above programme, where unexpected output  can be seen.
Output:

Created Linked List

a.b.c.d.e.f.)

a.b.c.d.ef.g.h.h.k.j.l.y.u.l.p

a.b.c.de.f.g)

Answer (score 1):

`malloc(sizeof(pattern))`

and then

`strcpy(new_node->pattern , pattern);` not correct.

better, use `strlen()` to get the received string length, then allocate memory, then perform `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` to copy the recived string.

Comment: i am surprised  how it still works for small size strings(5-7) character long.

Comment: @user3522354 Also, `pattern` is a pointer, so `sizeof(pattern)` is probably 8. If all your strings have 7 bytes or less, your incorrect code will work.

Comment: new_node->pattern = (char *)malloc(sizeof(pattern));
printf("sizeofpattern=%d", sizeof(new_node->pattern));It gives me 4 byte only not 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code , it will work. you must pass string length instead of string itself

```
    new_node->pattern = (char *)malloc(strlen(pattern)+1);

    /* put in the data  */

    memcpy(new_node->pattern , pattern,strlen(pattern)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct; however, there seems to be a dedicated function [`strdup`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252782/509868) to do what you want:

```
// Incorrect code
new_node->pattern = (char *)malloc(sizeof(pattern));
strcpy(new_node->pattern , pattern);

// Correct code, provided by user2083356
new_node->pattern = (char *)malloc(strlen(pattern)+1);
memcpy(new_node->pattern , pattern,strlen(pattern)+1);

// Does the same; seems easier to type and understand; also handles errors
new_node->pattern = strdup(pattern);
```

Comment: Thanks , but we can't have memory check in case malloc fails for strdup.