# access array using pointer to array stored in a struct C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct defined as following:

```
typedef char *element_t;

typedef
struct {
  element_t *array;     /* start of the array */
  int capacity;         /* number of elements the array */
  int length;           /* used portion of array, 0..capacity */
} list;
```

I am trying to access the array that `*array` points to and assign it a char value and print it.

I'm a bit rusty with C but this is how i'm trying to do it:

```
list.array[0] = "a";
printf("%s\n", list.array[0]);
```

This makes my program crash. Any fixes?

EDIT: I should also mention that I have done the following initialisations too:

```
element_t* array[LMAX];
list.array= *differentArray;
```

Comment: Are you assigning `list.array` to point to a valid array before the `list.array[0]` is accessed?

Comment: Just addressed that issue in my most recent edit in the OP

Comment: `array` is a pointer to pointer to char. You have to `strcpy(list.array[0],"a");` But this can crash too. You can first `malloc` it.

Comment: `list` is the name of a type. `list.array[0]` is an error because `.` can only be applied to objects.

Comment: Well, as my code example shows, `list` can also be a variable name in addition to being a name of a type.

Comment: It is however incredibly stupid practice to name your variables the same as the type...

Comment: ...if it actually was a type. This is C and AFAIK the standard library does not define a list type. Even if it was C++, it would be perfectly fine if you found yourself using namespaces as what they were designed for.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me:

```
typedef char *element_t;

typedef
struct {
  element_t *array;     /* start of the array */
  int capacity;         /* number of elements the array */
  int length;           /* used portion of array, 0..capacity */
} list;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    element_t array[2] = {"foo", "bar"};
    list list;
    list.array = array;
    list.capacity = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    list.length = 1;
    printf("%s\n", list.array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

You are most likely forgetting to assign `list.array` to point to a valid array.

Comment: What if I have a string that I'm going to parse using strtok, and I wish to add those tokens into the array? How would I be able to do that?

Comment: You need to allocate memory dynamically. Use `strdup(strtok(...))` and remember to check that memory allocation was successful (i.e. didn't return `NULL`) and exit with a clear error message it failed. Remember to also `free()` the memory allocated by `strdup()`. Note that `strdup()` isn't in standard C but it is typically nevertheless supported. `strtok` returns the same buffer every time but replaces the buffer contents which is why you need `strdup()`.

Comment: What does `strdup(strtok(...))` do? I just googled it but couldn't relate it to this particular situation

Comment: `strdup()`  allocates a new block of memory which is populated with the argument string. So, it essentially saves the string in the memory block used by `strtok()` which will be overwritten later in another `strtok()` call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c

Comment: Why is it necessary to do this? Can't we insert the token into the array right as we obtain it?

Comment: Well, the token points to a memory buffer that will be reused again the next time `strtok` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Change your initialization to:

```
element_t differentArray[LMAX];
list.array = &differentArray[0];
```

The rest of your code should work as is after this change. You don't need any further allocations as long as you only keep putting literals like `"a"` into it.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef char *element_t;` Don't hide pointers behind typedefs, this is bad practice as it makes the code unreadable. `element_t *array` will be the same as `char** array`. Is this actually what you want?

`list.array[0] = "a";` suggests that you intended "array" to be an array of pointers? Where do you allocate the actual array? Where do you initialize the struct? list.array[0] is pointing into la-la-land rather than at allocated memory, as far as I can tell from the posted code.

Also, the array of pointers need to be of type `const char*`, since you are pointing at string literals.

Comment: Actually, it is recommended to have the array of pointers as `const char *` when pointing at string literals, but not mandatory: in standard C, string literals are of type `char *`

Comment: @juhist Yes, but that is a known "bug" in the C standard.