# What is the diffrence between char *str="this is a string" from char *str = strdup("this is a string") in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals, strdup

What's the difference between the following code :

`char* str = "this is a string"`

From this one :

`char* str = strdup("this is a string")`

The usage scenarios ?

Comment: Also this question may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char *str="this is a string";
```

pointer `str` points to the first character of string literal "this is a string".
String literals 1) have static storage duration and 2) may not be changed.

Thus

```
str[0] = 'T'; // undefined behaviour
free( str ); // undefined behaviour
```

In this declaration

```
char *str = strdup("this is a string");
```

pointer str points to the first character of a dynamically allocated character array that contains string  "this is a string". You 1) have to free the memory when the array will not be needed any more and 2) you may change characters in the array.

```
str[0] = 'T'; // valid
free( str ); // valid
```

It might be said that in the first case the owner of the string is the compiler and in the second case the owner of the string is the programmer.:)

Comment: The statements are more than *declarations*: they are *definitions*.

Comment: @pmg There is no contradiction. A definition is at the same time a declaration.:)

Comment: Thank you so quick reply and your answer is very useful for me.

Comment: All definitions are declarations; some declarations are not definitions :)

Answer (score 3):

In `char *str = "this is a string";` the variable points to a read only memory area with the contents of the string.

In `char *str = strdup("this is a string");` the variable points to a writeable memory area 16 bytes long which the program must free at sometime to prevent memory leaks (or, in case of error, the variable is NULL).
Also note that `strdup()` is not described by the Standard and some implementations may not compile this version.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is detailed.

Comment: Also useful for me.^_^

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
char* str = "this is a string";
```

declares `str` a pointer pointing to a string literal. It can't be modified. While

```
char* str = strdup("this is a string");
```

declares `str` a pointer which point to the dynamically allocated memory returned by `strdup`. In this case `str` can be passed to `free`.