# Expression must be Modifiable lvalue (char array)

Tags: c++, struct, lvalue

I defined my struct as:

```
struct taxPayer{
  char name[25];
  long int socialSecNum;
  float taxRate;
  float income;
  float taxes; 
};
```

My main function contains:

```
taxPayer citizen1, citizen2;

citizen1.name = "Tim McGuiness";
citizen1.socialSecNum = 255871234;
citizen1.taxRate = 0.35;

citizen2.name = "John Kane";
citizen2.socialSecNum = 278990582;
citizen2.taxRate = 0.29;
```

The compiled gives me an error (C3863 array type `char[25]` is  not assignable, expression must be a modifiable lvalue) on `citizen1.name = "Tim McGuiness";` as well as on `citzen2.name = "John Kane";`

How do I remove this error and set `citizen1.name` to a name and `citizen2.name` to a different name?

Comment: Just change `char name[25]` to `const char*`. Or use `std::string`

Comment: Perfect, switched `char name[25]` to `char *name` and works exactly like it should.

Comment: @ZackSloan Switching to `char* name` doesn't work as you think. You need to allocate memory for it, otherwise it may seem to work, but you bump into undefined behaviour and the code will most likely crash. Stick to `std::string` if possible, and all these nightmares will be over.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't say switch to `char*`, I said `const char*`. Big difference. This will only make sense if the `name` is known at compile time. If you want to enter the `name` at runtime, then use `std::string`.

Comment: Or, if you really want, you can use `char*` as the type of `taxPayer::name`, in combination with [`strdup`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c), which takes care of the memory allocation for you: `citizen1.name = strdup("Tim McGuiness");`. But again, stick to C++ if you write C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array. What you can do is either use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or use [`std::strcpy/std::strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy), like

```
std::strncpy(citizen1.name,"Tim McGuiness", sizeof(taxPayer::name));
```

Since you use C++, I'd recommend using a `std::string`,

```
struct taxPayer
{
    std::string name;
    // the rest
};
```

then you can simply assign to it as you did in your code

```
citizen1.name = "Tim McGuiness";
```

Comment: Make sure that the [`strncpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) receives the maximum allowable length of the copy, i.e. the length of the `name[25]` array. Otherwise, a name longer than 25 characters (e.g. `"William Longhorn Emil Wastekovich"`) will create problems.

Comment: @Jens Sure, that's why I think OP should go with `std::string` (if using C++ and not C), otherwise of course `strncpy` with max length is the way to go for safe code.

Comment: If that is an option, then ok. If it is not and the OP has to use an array then extra attention is required.

Comment: Modified to `strncpy` just so OP avoids funky buffer overflows ;)

Comment: Please do not use `strncpy()` - if the source string is too long then the destination string is not terminated.  It also - rather wastefully - pads with additional NULs if the count is not reached after copying the source string (with its NUL terminator), 'strncpy()' isn't - and never was - intended for use as a "safe" 'strcpy()'.

Answer (score 3):

In c, an array is assignable only in the initialization period, citizen1.name is an array of char type. To solve your problem, you may use this:

```
strcpy(citizen1.name, "Tim McGuiness");
```

or:

```
memcpy(citizen1.name, "Tim McGuiness", strlen("Tim McGuiness"));
citizen1.name[strlen("Tim McGuiness") + 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of research, maybe it's a bit late but it may help someone over here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int i, j;

char cuvinte[5][10] = { "a", "b", "c",
                        "da", "e" };
char temp[10];
int lungime = sizeof(cuvinte) / sizeof(cuvinte[0]);

for (i = 0; i < lungime - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < lungime - 1; j++) {
        if (strcmp(cuvinte[j], cuvinte[j+1]) < 0) {
            strcpy_s(temp, cuvinte[j]);
            strcpy_s(cuvinte[j],cuvinte[j+1]);
            strcpy_s(cuvinte[j+1],temp);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < lungime;i++) {
    cout << cuvinte[i] << " ";
}


system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `char` array declaration:

```
char name[25];
```

This is a char array declaration **and initialization**, you assign char array initial value:

```
char name[25] = "String literal";
```

You cannot do this assignment latter in a code, because `name` is a *unmodifiable lvalue*, so you can use its value (which is string literal address in our case) but you cannot modify it (assign a new value).

OK:

```
char* p;
p = (name + 5);
```

NOK:

```
name = name + 5;
```

Comment: `name` is an lvalue, but not a modifiable one. You can confirm this by doing `decltype((name))` and checking the result with `std::is_lvalue_reference`.

Comment: yes you are right.  "Array expressions are lvalues as defined by the language specification; however, they are not modifiable lvalues, and so cannot be the target of an assignment"

Comment: Arrays are not always lvalues, it's possible to have rvalues too. E.g. if you have `using T = int[];`, then `T{1,2,3}` is an array rvalue. Or simply if you `std::move` an array.