# Trying to copy all strings from char*[] but get segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, string, shell, segmentation-fault

I am trying to figure out why I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to copy the arguments from one array of strings to another but just leaving out the >

```
int main(){
     char *args[] = {"sort", "myshell.c", ">", "2"};
     int size = 4*sizeof(args)/sizeof(args);
     char *temp[size];
     int i;

     printf("SIZE: %d\n", size);
     for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            if(strcmp(args[i], ">") > 0 || strcmp(args[i], ">") < 0 ){
                strcpy(temp[i],args[i]);

            }
            printf("arg: %s\n", temp[i]);
     }
```

Comment: `4*sizeof(args)/sizeof(args);` what is the purpose of multiplying and dividing by the same number?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed. Sorry about that, silly mistake, still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strcpy(temp[i],args[i]);
```

This is undefined behavior. `strcpy` tries to access an indeterminate memory location resulting in undefined behavior.

You need to allocate memory to `temp[i]` or simply use

```
temp[i]=strdup(args[i])
```

to copy the string to `temp[i]`.

Also

```
int size = 4*sizeof(args)/sizeof(args);
```

would be

```
int size = sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args);
```

If you know the length of the array to be 4 then what's the use of doing all those calculation. You need to calculate it not put it like that.

Example code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
     char *args[] = {"sort", "myshell.c", ">", "2"};
     size_t size = sizeof(args)/sizeof(*args);
     char *temp[size];
     size_t len = 0;
     printf("SIZE: %zu\n", size);
     for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            if(strcmp(args[i], ">") != 0 ){
                temp[len++] = args[i];
            }
     }
     for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("arg[%zu]: %s\n", i+1, temp[i]);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Note that your comparison should be much more simpler as mentioned above.

#### What does `strdup` do?

Internally it allocates memory and then copies the target string using `strcpy`. This is not part of the standard library and implemented by POSIX.
For more detail look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c) .

Comment: I fixed it by using that function you mention, strdup(), but I am not sure why? how does it work ?

Comment: @CodeDexter.: I have mentioned reference and a general idea. Hope it helps. Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes here at `strcpy(temp[i],args[i]);` as `temp[i]` has uninitialised values. You need allocate memory and store the address in `temp[i]` before calling `strcpy`

Answer (score 0):

1. You are trying to copy data (strings in this case) into the memory pointed by temp[i] - but this pointer is uninitialized and no memory is allocated.
   You should allocate memory:

   `temp[i] = (char )malloc(sizeof(char)(strlen(args[i])+1))`
2. To leave out the ">", you can just test for != 0. You will need a secondary index for the copied strings.
3. What is the purpose of sizeof(args)/sizeof(args)? 
   Try:

   ```
   int main()
   {
        char *args[] = {"sort", "myshell.c", ">", "2"};
        int size = sizeof(args)/sizeof(char *);
        char *temp[size];
        int i, j;

        printf("SIZE: %d\n", size);
        for (j = 0, i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
               if (strcmp(args[i], ">") != 0)
               {
                   temp[j] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(args[i])+1));
                   strcpy(temp[j],args[i]);
                   printf("arg: %s\n", temp[j]);
                   j++;
               }
        }
   }
   ```