# Issues with strtok in C

Tags: c, strtok

I have the following function in my code to extract names:

```
void student_init(struct student *s, char *info) {
    char *name;
    char *name2;
    char a[] = { *info };
    name = strtok(a, "/");
    strcpy(s->first_name, name);
    name2 = strtok(NULL, "/");
    strcpy(s->last_name, name2);
}
```

When I run this, I see:

```
Please enter a student information or enter "Q" to quit.
Daisy/Lee
A student information is read.: Daisy/Lee
Please enter a row number where the student wants to sit.
1
Please enter a column number where the student wants to sit.
2
The seat at row 1 and column 2 is assigned to the student: D . �
?.?. ?.?. ?.?.
?.?. ?.?. D.�.
?.?. ?.?. ?.?.
```

I am trying to use the strtok function in a c program to split a string with "/" to separate a fist and last name and store them in the first_name and last_name variables of a student strcuture.  I can get the first name stored in the respective variable but as you can see from the image in the link above I am getting a ? symbol in the output where the first initial of the last name should be.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code and output, we cannot copy&paste code from a picture and reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: `char a[] = { *info };` doesn't do what you think it does. Since `info` is a `char *`, `*info` is a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char a[] = { *info };
```

This is your problem. What this creates is a one-byte character array containing the first character of `info` and nothing else.

Since `strtok` requires a *string,* it's probably going to run off the end of that one-byte array and use whatever happens to be there in memory. That's why you're seeing the first character okay and not much else (though, technically, as undefined behaviour, literally *anything* is allowed to happen).

Rather than constructing a one-byte array, you should probably just use the string as it was passed in:

```
name = strtok(info, "/");
```

The only reason you would make a local copy is if the string you're tokenising was not allowed to be changed (such as if it were a string literal, or if you wanted to preserve it for later use). Since your sample run shows that you're reading *into* this string, it cannot be a string literal.

And, if you want to preserve it for later, that's probably a cost best incurred by the caller rather than the function (it's wasteful for the function to always make a duplicate when the information as to whether it's *needed* or not is known only to the caller).

In order to make a copy for tokenising, it's as simple as:

```
char originalString[] = "pax/diablo";

scratchString = strdup(originalString);
if (scratchString != NULL) {
    student_init (struct student *s, scratchString);
    free (scratchString);
} else {
    handleOutOfMemoryIssue();
}

useSafely (originalString);
```

If your implementation doesn't *have* `strdup` (it's POSIX rather than ISO), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802).

In my opinion, a "cleaner" implementation would be along the lines of:

```
void student_init (struct student *s, char *info) {
    // Default both to empty strings.

    *(s->first_name) = '\0';
    *(s->last_name) = '\0';

    // Try for first name, exit if none, otherwise save.

    char *field = strtok (info, "/");
    if (field == NULL) return;
    strcpy (s->first_name, field);

    // Try for second name, exit if none, otherwise save.

    if ((field = strtok (NULL, "/")) == NULL) return;
    strcpy (s->last_name, field);
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that `strtok` modifies its input. The caller likely isn't expecting that, so it is much safer to copy the input to the stack first.