# create a fake strdup

Tags: c, malloc, strdup

In this case I'm trying to understand the difference between this wrong `strdup` and the good one.

```
char *wrong_strdup(char *str) {
    char *dest;

    dest = str;
    return (dest);
}
```

Comment: All your function does is return its argument - i.e. it doesn't do anything. The real one does what it says it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/252802/4603670

Comment: The real `strdup` is basically doing two things: allocates *new* memory for the duplicate and *copies* the string into this new memory. Your implementation does neither.