# Is this a valid method to copy from one character pointer to other in c?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Is this a valid method to copy from one character pointer to other in c- `*char_ptr2++=*char_ptr1++`? I am not able to run the program, i think there is an error while copying from one character pointer to other.

Full Code-

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char* char_ptr1;
    char* char_ptr2;
    *char_ptr1="this is a string";
    while(*char_ptr1)
        *char_ptr2++=*char_ptr1++;
    printf("Entered string is %s",char_ptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this invokes *undefined behavior* - you didn't allocate any memory for `char_ptr2`

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory to copy it into.

Comment: `*char_ptr1="this is a string";` also shouldn't compile. `*char_ptr1` is a single `char`, it cannot hold a string

Comment: Will initializing it to NULL help?

Comment: No, you need to allocate memory, e.g.: by using `malloc`. You cannot just write into random addresses and assume things will work out

Comment: @Roshan No, you need to allocate memory. Either define it as an array and make sure that you don't overrun it (use `strncpy`), or dynamically allocate with `malloc`.

Comment: Even if it *did* work, you can't print the string like that. For one thing, it has no NUL terminator, for another `char_ptr2` is now pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: After allocating it memory. Can i use the above method to copy from ```char_ptr1```?

Comment: As @WeatherVane has just pointed out, you are not copying the NUL terminator. You will also need a temporary pointer variable for your loop so that you still keep a copy of the pointer to the start of the string, if you are going to actually use it for anything.

Answer (score 2):

Memory in C must be allocated. There's two basic types: stack or automatic memory, and heap or `malloc` memory. Stack is called "automatic" because it will be automatically freed for you once you leave the block. `heap` requires that you manually allocate and free the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{ 
    // A character array.
    char char_ptr1[] = "this is a string";

    // Allocate space for the string and its null byte.
    // sizeof(char_ptr1) only works to get the length on
    // char[]. On a *char it will return the size of the
    // pointer, not the length of the string.
    char* char_ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(char_ptr1));

    // We need copies of the pointers to iterate, else
    // we'll lose their original positions.
    char *src = char_ptr1;  // Arrays are read-only. The array will become a pointer.
    char *dest = char_ptr2;
    while(*src != '\0')
        *dest++ = *src++;
    // Don't forget the terminating null byte.
    *dest = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", char_ptr2);

    // All memory will be freed when the program exits, but it's good
    // practice to match every malloc with a free.
    free(char_ptr2);
}
```

The standard function to do this is `strcpy`. Be careful to be sure you've allocated sufficient memory, `strcpy` will not check for you.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char char_ptr1[] = "this is a string";
    char* char_ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(char_ptr1));

    strcpy(char_ptr2, char_ptr1);

    printf("%s\n", char_ptr2);

    free(char_ptr2);
}
```

And the POSIX function [`strdup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c) will handle both the allocation and copying for you.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char char_ptr1[] = "this is a string";
    char* char_ptr2 = strdup(char_ptr1);

    printf("%s\n", char_ptr2);

    free(char_ptr2);
}
```

Comment: Allocated memory is not generally a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), and there is no reason to describe it as such. At least with automatic memory, it is frequently (but not always) a stack, and there is a close association between the semantics required of automatic memory by the C standard and the behavior of a stack. But for allocated memory, there is no reason to mislead students by describing it as a heap. And there are not just two “types” of memory (storage durations); the C standard also specifies static and thread.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are technically correct! But this isn't a comprehensive review of C memory management. The goal is to help someone struggling with basic memory and string operations, they will not understand these nuances. I mention "heap" with `malloc` because [it is a common term they may have heard](https://study.cs50.net/malloc); they may not even know what a heap is. I understand there are more types of memory, that is why I said "basic types", and they are not relevant to the answer.