# How to dynamically allocate string size according to user input in C?

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

on googling i got an answer but i am not able to understand how it works. I have just started coding so i hope someone could explain the code clearly for me.

```
char *s;
s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", s);
s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Questioners should put some effort in their issues. Did you look up the documentation of `malloc()` and `realloc()`? Why did it not help you? What other insights did you have when reading introductory tutorials on the matter? What specifically is not clear?

Comment: This is terrible practice.  You should be wary of any code samples you get from this source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *s;       
s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
```

The above declares the variable `s` and assigns to it the address of a dynamically allocated chunk of memory large enough to hold 1024 chars.  However, no error checking is performed, so `s` may be NULL at this point.

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

This reads data from the input stream until a whitespace is encountered (or input terminates) and stores it in the allocated chunk of memory whose address is contained in `s` , appending a '\0' after the data that is read.  If there is more than 1023 bytes of data or if the previous `malloc` returned NULL, undefined behavior occurs. (This is bad.)

```
s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
```

This is an attempt to shrink the amount of memory being used so that `s` now points to a smaller chunk of memory which is just big enough to hold the string that was read.  The `+1` is in the 2nd argument to `realloc` because C stores strings as null terminated arrays, and it takes an extra character to store that terminator.  This is possibly a memory leak, since `realloc` can return NULL, in which case the original memory is lost and the program hasn't stored that value anywhere so cannot free it.

Do *not* *ever* *use* `"%s"` in a call to scanf.  If you have allocated N bytes for an array, use a width modifier of N - 1.  Often this means dynamically generating the format string, but often it is as simple as:

```
char s[32]; scanf("%31s", s);
```

Always check the value returned by `malloc`, `realloc`, and `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to shrinking the memory to the minimum needed for user input would be to allocate a second chunk of memory based on the size of the input, copy the string into it, then free the original.

*We're just going to assume `malloc` and `scanf` worked as we meant them tto and not error check for the purposes of this answer.*

```c
char *s1 = malloc(1024);
scanf("%1023s", s1);

char *s2 = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);
strcpy(s2, s1);

free(s1);
```

You might also use [`strdup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c).

Comment: Instead of creating a new string and copying the contents of the old string into it can't we just reallocate the size of the old string.      `realloc(s1,strlen(s1)+1);`   will do the job right or are there any problems in doing so?